# How to find list of possible words from a letter matrix [Boggle Solver]

Tags: algorithm, puzzle, boggle

Lately I have been playing a game on my iPhone called Scramble. Some of you may know this game as Boggle. Essentially, when the game starts you get a matrix of letters like so:

```
F X I E
A M L O
E W B X
A S T U
```

The goal of the game is to find as many words as you can that can be formed by chaining letters together. You can start with any letter, and all the letters that surround it are fair game, and then once you move on to the next letter, all the letters that surround that letter are fair game, **except for any previously used letters**. So in the grid above, for example, I could come up with the words `LOB`, `TUX`, `SEA`, `FAME`, etc. Words must be at least 3 characters, and no more than NxN characters, which would be 16 in this game but can vary in some implementations.  While this game is fun and addictive, I am apparently not very good at it and I wanted to cheat a little bit by making a program that would give me the best possible words (the longer the word the more points you get).

[image: Sample Boggle]
<sub>(source: [boggled.org](http://www.boggled.org/sample.gif))</sub>

I am, unfortunately, not very good with algorithms or their efficiencies and so forth. My first attempt uses a dictionary [such as this one](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/src/share/dict/web2?rev=1.12;content-type=text%2Fplain) (~2.3MB) and does a linear search trying to match combinations with dictionary entries. This takes a *very* long time to find the possible words, and since you only get 2 minutes per round, it is simply not adequate.

I am interested to see if any Stackoverflowers can come up with more efficient solutions. I am mostly looking for solutions using the Big 3 Ps: Python, PHP, and Perl, although anything with Java or C++ is cool too, since speed is essential.

**CURRENT SOLUTIONS**:

- Adam Rosenfield, Python, ~20s
- John Fouhy, Python, ~3s
- Kent Fredric, Perl, ~1s
- Darius Bacon, Python, ~1s
- rvarcher, VB.NET, ~1s
- Paolo Bergantino, PHP [(live link)](http://www.rootspot.com/stackoverflow/boggle.php), ~5s (~2s locally)

Comment: A simple solution is the class BoggleFinder http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/python/search.html

Comment: Well that's not very fun is it? :)

Comment: feature request MOAR PUZZLES

Comment: In regards to the timings: in my solution, practically all of the time is spent building the trie.  Once the trie is built, it can be reused many times.  If only solving one puzzle, it would be more efficient to use a simpler data structure (such as a set of all words and all prefixes).

Comment: Also, Adam's has a larger dictionary, evidenced by the number of longer words that his solution uses. They should all be tested based on a common dictionary.

Comment: @Rich: I'm running all of them on my computer with my own dictionary.

Comment: I guess no one plays much Boggle?  "Qu" is one "letter" and I'm not sure how many of the solutions caught that little detail.  It looks like some of them would allow you to use the "u" independently, among other problems.

Comment: I recently had this as an interview question and got nicely stuck in the details. I was treating it as a graph problem, which is fine, but the solutions here use far less space. I am coding up my own solution now. Well done to all who contributed!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about puzzle-solving. It would be more appropriate on http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Blazemonger The question is asking for the most efficient algorithm to solve a Boggle, not for the shortest one, and it is not a puzzle in the way codegolf wants. Last I checked algorithm related questions were fair game for StackOverflow. This is not off-topic, and I think the community has spoken pretty loudly on that.

Comment: You say you want a general algorithm, but "you're mostly looking" for concrete code in Python, PHP, or Perl. You haven't done any work on your own, which nowadays is considered essential for SO questions. Comments clearly identify this as a "puzzle" instead of a narrowly-defined problem with a single solution. Taken all together, it may or may not be suitable for codegolf as written, but if you'd submitted this question today, it certainly wouldn't be considered appropriate for SO. In my opinion, keeping it open sets a bad example for newcomers as to what's considered a "good question" here.

Comment: @Blazemonger 1. Asking for specific languages is irrelevant to it being an algorithm question. 2. I described my attempted solution and posted my own. 3. It is certainly narrow and defined enough. 4. It would certainly remain open if posted today. 5. If newcomers posted questions half as good as this one we'd be in good shape. In short, I respectfully disagree with virtually everything you said.

Comment: @PaoloBergantino Actually, open-ended questions that encourage analytical thinking are way better than the "do my job while I go have lunch" type so-called newcomer questions that are so prevalent on SO these days.

Comment: I expect this Q could get a historical lock, since there is value in the answers, but I agree it's not on-topic. I'll try again for closing. cc @Blazemonger.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

My answer works like the others here, but I'll post it because it looks a bit faster than the other Python solutions, from setting up the dictionary faster. (I checked this against John Fouhy's solution.) After setup, the time to solve is down in the noise.

```python
grid = "fxie amlo ewbx astu".split()
nrows, ncols = len(grid), len(grid[0])

# A dictionary word that could be a solution must use only the grid's
# letters and have length >= 3. (With a case-insensitive match.)
import re
alphabet = ''.join(set(''.join(grid)))
bogglable = re.compile('[' + alphabet + ']{3,}$', re.I).match

words = set(word.rstrip('\n') for word in open('words') if bogglable(word))
prefixes = set(word[:i] for word in words
               for i in range(2, len(word)+1))

def solve():
    for y, row in enumerate(grid):
        for x, letter in enumerate(row):
            for result in extending(letter, ((x, y),)):
                yield result

def extending(prefix, path):
    if prefix in words:
        yield (prefix, path)
    for (nx, ny) in neighbors(path[-1]):
        if (nx, ny) not in path:
            prefix1 = prefix + grid[ny][nx]
            if prefix1 in prefixes:
                for result in extending(prefix1, path + ((nx, ny),)):
                    yield result

def neighbors((x, y)):
    for nx in range(max(0, x-1), min(x+2, ncols)):
        for ny in range(max(0, y-1), min(y+2, nrows)):
            yield (nx, ny)
```

Sample usage:

```
# Print a maximal-length word and its path:
print max(solve(), key=lambda (word, path): len(word))
```

**Edit:** Filter out words less than 3 letters long.

**Edit 2:** I was curious why Kent Fredric's Perl solution was faster; it turns out to use regular-expression matching instead of a set of characters. Doing the same in Python about doubles the speed.

Comment: The program is only giving me 1 word. How come?

Comment: I didn't want to drown in output. See the comment at the bottom.

Comment: Or get all the words without the paths: print ' '.join(sorted(set(word for (word, path) in solve())))

Comment: Much of the time is spent just parsing the dictionary.  I pre-parsed that out into a "wordlines.py" file that is just a list with each word being an element.  Because it's a .py file, that will get turned into a .pyc file.  So then I do an import of that instead of the read().splitlines().  With that, on my box, I'm solving it in around a tenth of a second.

Comment: no idea why, as i'm not a seasoned python dev, but i get all kinds of errors on python 3.30 on windows.

Comment: @shellscape, it's Python 2 code. Python 3 dropped the ability to deconstruct arguments, like `def neighbors((x, y))` (pointlessly, as far as I can see). Also it requires parentheses around the argument to `print`.

Comment: @DariusBacon or anyone else if they can, for someone who isn't too familiar with python to immediately understand, what is it that your code is doing that its faster? I understand that tries are optimal for looking for valid words, but how exactly are you eliminating words from the dictonary that don't exist on the board according to the header comment "must use the grid's letters" Do you look at every index on the board, removing words from the dictionary, and then restart to compute the boggle's bords actual words?

Comment: @user999999928 the dictionary (`words`) is built out of only the `bogglable` words: the words made up only of letters that appear in the grid, at least 3 letters long. This is done right at the start, so there's no restarting. About tries, in Python they have a lot of overhead compared to a dict (Python's built-in hashtable structure).

Comment: Any time you're doing `for result in ...: yield result`, you can simplify this to `yield from ...`.

Comment: @DariusBacon why you are sum `len(word)` in prefixes, while you must `len(word)-1` !! Or what do I mistake?!

Comment: @SAt I'm not sure I understand your question. `prefixes` includes each whole word as well as the shorter prefixes of each word. The logic is simpler if you define it that way.

Comment: @kaya3 good point. This was written in Python 2. It'd be nice if someone wants to bring this up to current Python.

Answer (score 117):

The fastest solution you're going to get will probably involve storing your dictionary in a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).  Then, create a queue of triplets (*x*, *y*, *s*), where each element in the queue corresponds to a prefix *s* of a word which can be spelled in the grid, ending at location (*x*, *y*).  Initialize the queue with *N* x *N* elements (where *N* is the size of your grid), one element for each square in the grid.  Then, the algorithm proceeds as follows:

```
While the queue is not empty:
  Dequeue a triple (x, y, s)
  For each square (x', y') with letter c adjacent to (x, y):
    If s+c is a word, output s+c
    If s+c is a prefix of a word, insert (x', y', s+c) into the queue
```

If you store your dictionary in a trie, testing if *s*+*c* is a word or a prefix of a word can be done in constant time (provided you also keep some extra metadata in each queue datum, such as a pointer to the current node in the trie), so the running time of this algorithm is O(number of words that can be spelled).

**[Edit]** Here's an implementation in Python that I just coded up:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python

class TrieNode:
    def __init__(self, parent, value):
        self.parent = parent
        self.children = [None] * 26
        self.isWord = False
        if parent is not None:
            parent.children[ord(value) - 97] = self

def MakeTrie(dictfile):
    dict = open(dictfile)
    root = TrieNode(None, '')
    for word in dict:
        curNode = root
        for letter in word.lower():
            if 97 <= ord(letter) < 123:
                nextNode = curNode.children[ord(letter) - 97]
                if nextNode is None:
                    nextNode = TrieNode(curNode, letter)
                curNode = nextNode
        curNode.isWord = True
    return root

def BoggleWords(grid, dict):
    rows = len(grid)
    cols = len(grid[0])
    queue = []
    words = []
    for y in range(cols):
        for x in range(rows):
            c = grid[y][x]
            node = dict.children[ord(c) - 97]
            if node is not None:
                queue.append((x, y, c, node))
    while queue:
        x, y, s, node = queue[0]
        del queue[0]
        for dx, dy in ((1, 0), (1, -1), (0, -1), (-1, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1), (0, 1), (1, 1)):
            x2, y2 = x + dx, y + dy
            if 0 <= x2 < cols and 0 <= y2 < rows:
                s2 = s + grid[y2][x2]
                node2 = node.children[ord(grid[y2][x2]) - 97]
                if node2 is not None:
                    if node2.isWord:
                        words.append(s2)
                    queue.append((x2, y2, s2, node2))

    return words
```

Example usage:

```python
d = MakeTrie('/usr/share/dict/words')
print(BoggleWords(['fxie','amlo','ewbx','astu'], d))
```

Output:

> ['fa', 'xi', 'ie', 'io', 'el', 'am', 'ax', 'ae', 'aw', 'mi', 'ma', 'me', 'lo', 'li', 'oe', 'ox', 'em', 'ea', 'ea', 'es', 'wa', 'we', 'wa', 'bo', 'bu', 'as', 'aw', 'ae', 'st', 'se', 'sa', 'tu', 'ut', 'fam', 'fae', 'imi', 'eli', 'elm', 'elb', 'ami', 'ama', 'ame', 'aes', 'awl', 'awa', 'awe', 'awa', 'mix', 'mim', 'mil', 'mam', 'max', 'mae', 'maw', 'mew', 'mem', 'mes', 'lob', 'lox', 'lei', 'leo', 'lie', 'lim', 'oil', 'olm', 'ewe', 'eme', 'wax', 'waf', 'wae', 'waw', 'wem', 'wea', 'wea', 'was', 'waw', 'wae', 'bob', 'blo', 'bub', 'but', 'ast', 'ase', 'asa', 'awl', 'awa', 'awe', 'awa', 'aes', 'swa', 'swa', 'sew', 'sea', 'sea', 'saw', 'tux', 'tub', 'tut', 'twa', 'twa', 'tst', 'utu', 'fama', 'fame', 'ixil', 'imam', 'amli', 'amil', 'ambo', 'axil', 'axle', 'mimi', 'mima', 'mime', 'milo', 'mile', 'mewl', 'mese', 'mesa', 'lolo', 'lobo', 'lima', 'lime', 'limb', 'lile', 'oime', 'oleo', 'olio', 'oboe', 'obol', 'emim', 'emil', 'east', 'ease', 'wame', 'wawa', 'wawa', 'weam', 'west', 'wese', 'wast', 'wase', 'wawa', 'wawa', 'boil', 'bolo', 'bole', 'bobo', 'blob', 'bleo', 'bubo', 'asem', 'stub', 'stut', 'swam', 'semi', 'seme', 'seam', 'seax', 'sasa', 'sawt', 'tutu', 'tuts', 'twae', 'twas', 'twae', 'ilima', 'amble', 'axile', 'awest', 'mamie', 'mambo', 'maxim', 'mease', 'mesem', 'limax', 'limes', 'limbo', 'limbu', 'obole', 'emesa', 'embox', 'awest', 'swami', 'famble', 'mimble', 'maxima', 'embolo', 'embole', 'wamble', 'semese', 'semble', 'sawbwa', 'sawbwa']

Notes: This program doesn't output 1-letter words, or filter by word length at all.  That's easy to add but not really relevant to the problem.  It also outputs some words multiple times if they can be spelled in multiple ways.  If a given word can be spelled in many different ways (worst case: every letter in the grid is the same (e.g. 'A') and a word like 'aaaaaaaaaa' is in your dictionary), then the running time will get horribly exponential.  Filtering out duplicates and sorting is trivial to due after the algorithm has finished.

Comment: Ooo. I'm glad someone stepped up to the plate. Although this works, it doesn't "remember" the letter it has already used, and comes up with words that would require using the same letter twice which is not allowed. As I'm an idiot, how would I go about fixing that?

Comment: True, it doesn't remember what letters have been visited, but that wasn't specified in your spec =).  To fix that, you'd have to add to each queue datum a list of all the visited locations, and then check that list before adding the next character.

Comment: No, inside BoggleWords().  Instead of storing a quadruplet (x, y, s, n), you'd store a quintuplet (x, y, s, n, l), where l is the list of (x, y)'s visited so far.  Then you check each (x2, y2) against l and accept it only if it's not in l.  Then you add it to the new l.

Comment: Its *reasonably* simple if you're already doing path tracking, just look at the current path for a future node before attempting to revisit again on the same path. Its a suboptimal, but for what were doing its below IO threshold.

Comment: By the way, you should only need to generate all of the permutations of legal sequences for an NxN grid once for each value of N.  That list isn't dependent on the letters in the grid.

Comment: I did this too when I got sick of playing Scramble.  I think the recursive (DFS instead of BFS) solution is more sexy, as you can just keep a set of active cells (so you don't visit the same cell twice).  Much neater then keeping a bunch of lists.

Comment: Shouldn't this fall into an infinite loop? I mean, say for `(x,y)`, a possible follower is `(x+1,y+1)`. Then `(x+1,y+1)` is pushed to the queue. However `(x,y)` will too be a follower for `(x+1,y+1)`, so won't that lead to an unending bouncing back between them?

Comment: @AdamRosenfield sorry for asking a question for a solution which is more than 4 years old. But the question attracts most of the visitors in SO. So anyways my question is: "Eventually after adding a char to the current string will not be present in the dictionary hence rejecting the node form the queue. So after certain time the queue will be empty and this is the terminating condition. Am i correct?". And Cant we use a data structure to check whether the coordinate is traversed or not if not than add else reject which will be more efficient because in this solution there are lot of repetition

Comment: Nice solution!  My question is why did you use a queue instead of a stack?  Is there any particular advantage one has over the other?

Comment: I converted this to javascript, the implementation is here: https://gist.github.com/JonnoFTW/fbdc5079174c3bb448e0951de9ebbe94

Answer (score 39):

For a dictionary speedup, there is one general transformation/process you can do to greatly reduce the dictionary comparisons ahead of time.

Given that the above grid contains only 16 characters, some of them duplicate, you can greatly reduce the number of total keys in your dictionary by simply filtering out entries that have unattainable characters.

I thought this was the obvious optimization but seeing nobody did it I'm mentioning it.

It reduced me from a dictionary of 200,000 keys to only 2,000 keys simply during the input pass. This at the very least reduces memory overhead, and that's sure to map to a speed increase somewhere as memory isn't infinitely fast.

### Perl Implementation

My implementation is a bit top-heavy because I placed importance on being able to know the exact path of every extracted string, not just the validity therein.

I also have a few adaptions in there that would theoretically permit a grid with holes in it to function, and grids with different sized lines ( assuming you get the input right and it lines up somehow ).

The early-filter is by far the most *significant* bottleneck in my application, as suspected earlier, commenting out that line bloats it from 1.5s to 7.5s.

Upon execution it appears to think all the single digits are on their own valid words,  but I'm pretty sure thats due to how the dictionary file works.

Its a bit bloated, but at least I reuse [Tree::Trie](http://p3rl.org/Tree::Trie) from cpan

Some of it was inspired partially by the existing implementations, some of it I had in mind already.

Constructive Criticism and ways it could be improved welcome ( /me notes he never [searched CPAN for a boggle solver](http://p3rl.org/Games::Boggle), but this was more fun to work out )

**updated for new criteria**

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;

{

  # this package manages a given path through the grid.
  # Its an array of matrix-nodes in-order with
  # Convenience functions for pretty-printing the paths
  # and for extending paths as new paths.

  # Usage:
  # my $p = Prefix->new(path=>[ $startnode ]);
  # my $c = $p->child( $extensionNode );
  # print $c->current_word ;

  package Prefix;
  use Moose;

  has path => (
      isa     => 'ArrayRef[MatrixNode]',
      is      => 'rw',
      default => sub { [] },
  );
  has current_word => (
      isa        => 'Str',
      is         => 'rw',
      lazy_build => 1,
  );

  # Create a clone of this object
  # with a longer path

  # $o->child( $successive-node-on-graph );

  sub child {
      my $self    = shift;
      my $newNode = shift;
      my $f       = Prefix->new();

      # Have to do this manually or other recorded paths get modified
      push @{ $f->{path} }, @{ $self->{path} }, $newNode;
      return $f;
  }

  # Traverses $o->path left-to-right to get the string it represents.

  sub _build_current_word {
      my $self = shift;
      return join q{}, map { $_->{value} } @{ $self->{path} };
  }

  # Returns  the rightmost node on this path

  sub tail {
      my $self = shift;
      return $self->{path}->[-1];
  }

  # pretty-format $o->path

  sub pp_path {
      my $self = shift;
      my @path =
        map { '[' . $_->{x_position} . ',' . $_->{y_position} . ']' }
        @{ $self->{path} };
      return "[" . join( ",", @path ) . "]";
  }

  # pretty-format $o
  sub pp {
      my $self = shift;
      return $self->current_word . ' => ' . $self->pp_path;
  }

  __PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
}

{

  # Basic package for tracking node data
  # without having to look on the grid.
  # I could have just used an array or a hash, but that got ugly.

# Once the matrix is up and running it doesn't really care so much about rows/columns,
# Its just a sea of points and each point has adjacent points.
# Relative positioning is only really useful to map it back to userspace

  package MatrixNode;
  use Moose;

  has x_position => ( isa => 'Int', is => 'rw', required => 1 );
  has y_position => ( isa => 'Int', is => 'rw', required => 1 );
  has value      => ( isa => 'Str', is => 'rw', required => 1 );
  has siblings   => (
      isa     => 'ArrayRef[MatrixNode]',
      is      => 'rw',
      default => sub { [] }
  );

# Its not implicitly uni-directional joins. It would be more effient in therory
# to make the link go both ways at the same time, but thats too hard to program around.
# and besides, this isn't slow enough to bother caring about.

  sub add_sibling {
      my $self    = shift;
      my $sibling = shift;
      push @{ $self->siblings }, $sibling;
  }

  # Convenience method to derive a path starting at this node

  sub to_path {
      my $self = shift;
      return Prefix->new( path => [$self] );
  }
  __PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

}

{

  package Matrix;
  use Moose;

  has rows => (
      isa     => 'ArrayRef',
      is      => 'rw',
      default => sub { [] },
  );

  has regex => (
      isa        => 'Regexp',
      is         => 'rw',
      lazy_build => 1,
  );

  has cells => (
      isa        => 'ArrayRef',
      is         => 'rw',
      lazy_build => 1,
  );

  sub add_row {
      my $self = shift;
      push @{ $self->rows }, [@_];
  }

  # Most of these functions from here down are just builder functions,
  # or utilities to help build things.
  # Some just broken out to make it easier for me to process.
  # All thats really useful is add_row
  # The rest will generally be computed, stored, and ready to go
  # from ->cells by the time either ->cells or ->regex are called.

  # traverse all cells and make a regex that covers them.
  sub _build_regex {
      my $self  = shift;
      my $chars = q{};
      for my $cell ( @{ $self->cells } ) {
          $chars .= $cell->value();
      }
      $chars = "[^$chars]";
      return qr/$chars/i;
  }

  # convert a plain cell ( ie: [x][y] = 0 )
  # to an intelligent cell ie: [x][y] = object( x, y )
  # we only really keep them in this format temporarily
  # so we can go through and tie in neighbouring information.
  # after the neigbouring is done, the grid should be considered inoperative.

  sub _convert {
      my $self = shift;
      my $x    = shift;
      my $y    = shift;
      my $v    = $self->_read( $x, $y );
      my $n    = MatrixNode->new(
          x_position => $x,
          y_position => $y,
          value      => $v,
      );
      $self->_write( $x, $y, $n );
      return $n;
  }

# go through the rows/collums presently available and freeze them into objects.

  sub _build_cells {
      my $self = shift;
      my @out  = ();
      my @rows = @{ $self->{rows} };
      for my $x ( 0 .. $#rows ) {
          next unless defined $self->{rows}->[$x];
          my @col = @{ $self->{rows}->[$x] };
          for my $y ( 0 .. $#col ) {
              next unless defined $self->{rows}->[$x]->[$y];
              push @out, $self->_convert( $x, $y );
          }
      }
      for my $c (@out) {
          for my $n ( $self->_neighbours( $c->x_position, $c->y_position ) ) {
              $c->add_sibling( $self->{rows}->[ $n->[0] ]->[ $n->[1] ] );
          }
      }
      return \@out;
  }

  # given x,y , return array of points that refer to valid neighbours.
  sub _neighbours {
      my $self = shift;
      my $x    = shift;
      my $y    = shift;
      my @out  = ();
      for my $sx ( -1, 0, 1 ) {
          next if $sx + $x < 0;
          next if not defined $self->{rows}->[ $sx + $x ];
          for my $sy ( -1, 0, 1 ) {
              next if $sx == 0 && $sy == 0;
              next if $sy + $y < 0;
              next if not defined $self->{rows}->[ $sx + $x ]->[ $sy + $y ];
              push @out, [ $sx + $x, $sy + $y ];
          }
      }
      return @out;
  }

  sub _has_row {
      my $self = shift;
      my $x    = shift;
      return defined $self->{rows}->[$x];
  }

  sub _has_cell {
      my $self = shift;
      my $x    = shift;
      my $y    = shift;
      return defined $self->{rows}->[$x]->[$y];
  }

  sub _read {
      my $self = shift;
      my $x    = shift;
      my $y    = shift;
      return $self->{rows}->[$x]->[$y];
  }

  sub _write {
      my $self = shift;
      my $x    = shift;
      my $y    = shift;
      my $v    = shift;
      $self->{rows}->[$x]->[$y] = $v;
      return $v;
  }

  __PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
}

use Tree::Trie;

sub readDict {
  my $fn = shift;
  my $re = shift;
  my $d  = Tree::Trie->new();

  # Dictionary Loading
  open my $fh, '<', $fn;
  while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
      chomp($line);

 # Commenting the next line makes it go from 1.5 seconds to 7.5 seconds. EPIC.
      next if $line =~ $re;    # Early Filter
      $d->add( uc($line) );
  }
  return $d;
}

sub traverseGraph {
  my $d     = shift;
  my $m     = shift;
  my $min   = shift;
  my $max   = shift;
  my @words = ();

  # Inject all grid nodes into the processing queue.

  my @queue =
    grep { $d->lookup( $_->current_word ) }
    map  { $_->to_path } @{ $m->cells };

  while (@queue) {
      my $item = shift @queue;

      # put the dictionary into "exact match" mode.

      $d->deepsearch('exact');

      my $cword = $item->current_word;
      my $l     = length($cword);

      if ( $l >= $min && $d->lookup($cword) ) {
          push @words,
            $item;    # push current path into "words" if it exactly matches.
      }
      next if $l > $max;

      # put the dictionary into "is-a-prefix" mode.
      $d->deepsearch('boolean');

    siblingloop: foreach my $sibling ( @{ $item->tail->siblings } ) {
          foreach my $visited ( @{ $item->{path} } ) {
              next siblingloop if $sibling == $visited;
          }

          # given path y , iterate for all its end points
          my $subpath = $item->child($sibling);

          # create a new path for each end-point
          if ( $d->lookup( $subpath->current_word ) ) {

             # if the new path is a prefix, add it to the bottom of the queue.
              push @queue, $subpath;
          }
      }
  }
  return \@words;
}

sub setup_predetermined { 
  my $m = shift; 
  my $gameNo = shift;
  if( $gameNo == 0 ){
      $m->add_row(qw( F X I E ));
      $m->add_row(qw( A M L O ));
      $m->add_row(qw( E W B X ));
      $m->add_row(qw( A S T U ));
      return $m;
  }
  if( $gameNo == 1 ){
      $m->add_row(qw( D G H I ));
      $m->add_row(qw( K L P S ));
      $m->add_row(qw( Y E U T ));
      $m->add_row(qw( E O R N ));
      return $m;
  }
}
sub setup_random { 
  my $m = shift; 
  my $seed = shift;
  srand $seed;
  my @letters = 'A' .. 'Z' ; 
  for( 1 .. 4 ){ 
      my @r = ();
      for( 1 .. 4 ){
          push @r , $letters[int(rand(25))];
      }
      $m->add_row( @r );
  }
}

# Here is where the real work starts.

my $m = Matrix->new();
setup_predetermined( $m, 0 );
#setup_random( $m, 5 );

my $d = readDict( 'dict.txt', $m->regex );
my $c = scalar @{ $m->cells };    # get the max, as per spec

print join ",\n", map { $_->pp } @{
  traverseGraph( $d, $m, 3, $c ) ;
};
```

Arch/execution info for comparison:

```
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T9300  @ 2.50GHz
cache size      : 6144 KB
Memory usage summary: heap total: 77057577, heap peak: 11446200, stack peak: 26448
       total calls   total memory   failed calls
 malloc|     947212       68763684              0
realloc|      11191        1045641              0  (nomove:9063, dec:4731, free:0)
 calloc|     121001        7248252              0
   free|     973159       65854762

Histogram for block sizes:
  0-15         392633  36% ==================================================
 16-31          43530   4% =====
 32-47          50048   4% ======
 48-63          70701   6% =========
 64-79          18831   1% ==
 80-95          19271   1% ==
 96-111        238398  22% ==============================
112-127          3007  <1% 
128-143        236727  21% ==============================
```

### More Mumblings on that Regex Optimization

The regex optimization I use is useless for multi-solve dictionaries, and for multi-solve you'll want a full dictionary, not a pre-trimmed one.

However, that said, for one-off solves, its really fast. ( Perl regex are in C! :)  )

Here is some varying code additions:

```perl
sub readDict_nofilter {
  my $fn = shift;
  my $re = shift;
  my $d  = Tree::Trie->new();

  # Dictionary Loading
  open my $fh, '<', $fn;
  while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
      chomp($line);
      $d->add( uc($line) );
  }
  return $d;
}

sub benchmark_io { 
  use Benchmark qw( cmpthese :hireswallclock );
   # generate a random 16 character string 
   # to simulate there being an input grid. 
  my $regexen = sub { 
      my @letters = 'A' .. 'Z' ; 
      my @lo = ();
      for( 1..16 ){ 
          push @lo , $_ ; 
      }
      my $c  = join '', @lo;
      $c = "[^$c]";
      return qr/$c/i;
  };
  cmpthese( 200 , { 
      filtered => sub { 
          readDict('dict.txt', $regexen->() );
      }, 
      unfiltered => sub {
          readDict_nofilter('dict.txt');
      }
  });
}
```

```
           s/iter unfiltered   filtered
unfiltered   8.16         --       -94%
filtered    0.464      1658%         --
```

<sub>ps: 8.16 * 200 = 27 minutes.</sub>

Comment: I know I'm failing the optimization club, but I had speed issues before I got to the real work of the code, and reducing input time from 2s to 1.2s means a lot to me.

Comment: /me noted it odd now it took *less* time to regex and skip entries than it took to add keys to a hash.

Comment: Nice, a Perl implementation! I'll go run it now.

Comment: Blerg, having a hard time installing Tree::Trie on my webserver. :(

Comment: Paolo: Simply putting Trie.pm from the CPAN distribution into a "lib/Tree" directory and then adding "use lib 'path/to/that/lib';" to the top of the program should do the trick in this case.

Comment: Yeah, Tree::Trie fails the POD tests for some reason, its pretty bollocks, so if you're installing w/ cpan you'll want to force it somehow to continue on test failure.

Comment: Thanks; I'll try that. By the way, John Fouhy's is correct in that once you use one node in a word, you can't use it again. That was my bad on the OP for not making that clear, I've updated the question.

Comment: ugh. pesky. just as well I record the path then. I can just eliminate it after-the-fact :p

Comment: also, I'm progressively accelerating my code, I just halved its runtime, my  biggest bottleneck is IO at present.

Comment: Well my dumb webhost is being impossible, I got Trie working but now I'm getting errors with Moose, so just let me know your runtimes and I'll update the post. I'm working on my own PHP implementation right now, and I'll eventually put a bounty on this, just for fun. :)

Comment: My current bests are around 1.116s, but of that 400ms is reported as just *reading* the dictionary. /tmp/dict.txt is on a tmpfs, so...

Comment: Are you using the same dict as the question or a different one?

Comment: same dictionary as posted in question @ 2.2mb

Comment: I'm not sure why you have listed me @ 1millisecond (ms), 1.116 is 1 thousand milliseconds and then some.

Comment: I'm not  even sure if python can *load* in >100ms

Comment: Whooops, I meant seconds, not ms, I fixed that sorry. :)

Comment: Average over 50 runs with printing: 1.019s Real, 0.970s user, 0.018 sys

Comment: without print: 1.001 real, 0.962 user 0.019 sys

Comment: How did you generate that last report (arch/execution info)? Looks useful.

Comment: arch I sucked out of /proc/cpuinfo , the rest is "memusage", which is a utility bundled with glibc.

Comment: Out of interest, does filtering on multiple letters help at all? For instance, the example board only has one `T` so that you could exclude all words with two or more `T`s.

Comment: @Neil Multi-letter filter *might* help, but it could hinder too, because the regexp I use is a simple character set, it boils down to a simple C level scan-until-non-match-found routine.

Duplicate character filter may reduce the trie computation side, but it could cost enough to make the optimisation not worth it, because you'd need to introduce some kind of state tracking code to determine character arity, and that gets messy as a regexp, and may introduce regexp side effects like backtracking.

Answer (score 34):

You could split the problem up into two pieces:

1. Some kind of search algorithm that will enumerate possible strings in the grid.
2. A way of testing whether a string is a valid word.

Ideally, (2) should also include a way of testing whether a string is a prefix of a valid word – this will allow you to prune your search and save a whole heap of time.

Adam Rosenfield's Trie is a solution to (2).  It's elegant and probably what your algorithms specialist would prefer, but with modern languages and modern computers, we can be a bit lazier.  Also, as Kent suggests, we can reduce our dictionary size by discarding words that have letters not present in the grid.  Here's some python:

```
def make_lookups(grid, fn='dict.txt'):
    # Make set of valid characters.
    chars = set()
    for word in grid:
        chars.update(word)

    words = set(x.strip() for x in open(fn) if set(x.strip()) <= chars)
    prefixes = set()
    for w in words:
        for i in range(len(w)+1):
            prefixes.add(w[:i])

    return words, prefixes
```

Wow; constant-time prefix testing.  It takes a couple of seconds to load the dictionary you linked, but only a couple :-) (notice that `words <= prefixes`)

Now, for part (1), I'm inclined to think in terms of graphs.  So I'll build a dictionary that looks something like this:

```
graph = { (x, y):set([(x0,y0), (x1,y1), (x2,y2)]), }
```

i.e. `graph[(x, y)]` is the set of coordinates that you can reach from position `(x, y)`.  I'll also add a dummy node `None` which will connect to everything.

Building it's a bit clumsy, because there's 8 possible positions and you have to do bounds checking.  Here's some correspondingly-clumsy python code:

```
def make_graph(grid):
    root = None
    graph = { root:set() }
    chardict = { root:'' }

    for i, row in enumerate(grid):
        for j, char in enumerate(row):
            chardict[(i, j)] = char
            node = (i, j)
            children = set()
            graph[node] = children
            graph[root].add(node)
            add_children(node, children, grid)

    return graph, chardict

def add_children(node, children, grid):
    x0, y0 = node
    for i in [-1,0,1]:
        x = x0 + i
        if not (0 <= x < len(grid)):
            continue
        for j in [-1,0,1]:
            y = y0 + j
            if not (0 <= y < len(grid[0])) or (i == j == 0):
                continue

            children.add((x,y))
```

This code also builds up a dictionary mapping `(x,y)` to the corresponding character.  This lets me turn a list of positions into a word:

```
def to_word(chardict, pos_list):
    return ''.join(chardict[x] for x in pos_list)
```

Finally, we do a depth-first search.  The basic procedure is:

1. The search arrives at a particular node.
2. Check if the path so far could be part of a word.  If not, don't explore this branch any further.
3. Check if the path so far is a word.  If so, add to the list of results.
4. Explore all children not part of the path so far.

Python:

```
def find_words(graph, chardict, position, prefix, results, words, prefixes):
    """ Arguments:
      graph :: mapping (x,y) to set of reachable positions
      chardict :: mapping (x,y) to character
      position :: current position (x,y) -- equals prefix[-1]
      prefix :: list of positions in current string
      results :: set of words found
      words :: set of valid words in the dictionary
      prefixes :: set of valid words or prefixes thereof
    """
    word = to_word(chardict, prefix)

    if word not in prefixes:
        return

    if word in words:
        results.add(word)

    for child in graph[position]:
        if child not in prefix:
            find_words(graph, chardict, child, prefix+[child], results, words, prefixes)
```

Run the code as:

```
grid = ['fxie', 'amlo', 'ewbx', 'astu']
g, c = make_graph(grid)
w, p = make_lookups(grid)
res = set()
find_words(g, c, None, [], res, w, p)
```

and inspect `res` to see the answers.  Here's a list of words found for your example, sorted by size:

```
 ['a', 'b', 'e', 'f', 'i', 'l', 'm', 'o', 's', 't',
 'u', 'w', 'x', 'ae', 'am', 'as', 'aw', 'ax', 'bo',
 'bu', 'ea', 'el', 'em', 'es', 'fa', 'ie', 'io', 'li',
 'lo', 'ma', 'me', 'mi', 'oe', 'ox', 'sa', 'se', 'st',
 'tu', 'ut', 'wa', 'we', 'xi', 'aes', 'ame', 'ami',
 'ase', 'ast', 'awa', 'awe', 'awl', 'blo', 'but', 'elb',
 'elm', 'fae', 'fam', 'lei', 'lie', 'lim', 'lob', 'lox',
 'mae', 'maw', 'mew', 'mil', 'mix', 'oil', 'olm', 'saw',
 'sea', 'sew', 'swa', 'tub', 'tux', 'twa', 'wae', 'was',
 'wax', 'wem', 'ambo', 'amil', 'amli', 'asem', 'axil',
 'axle', 'bleo', 'boil', 'bole', 'east', 'fame', 'limb',
 'lime', 'mesa', 'mewl', 'mile', 'milo', 'oime', 'sawt',
 'seam', 'seax', 'semi', 'stub', 'swam', 'twae', 'twas',
 'wame', 'wase', 'wast', 'weam', 'west', 'amble', 'awest',
 'axile', 'embox', 'limbo', 'limes', 'swami', 'embole',
 'famble', 'semble', 'wamble']
```

The code takes (literally) a couple of seconds to load the dictionary, but the rest is instant on my machine.

Comment: Very nice! Very fast, too. I'm going to wait around to see if anyone else steps up to the plate, but your answer is looking good so far.

Comment: I'm confused why "embole" is your only 6-letter word, I got 10 different words for that. It appears you prohibit visiting the same node twice, and as the OP stated, that's fair game.

Comment: ok, hes still possibly got a bug as hes discarding "FAMBLE" "WAMBLE" and "SEMBLE", which don't share characters.

Comment: Well spotted!  The bug was in the creation of the prefixes set: I needed to use `range(len(w)+1)` instead of `range(len(w))`.  I claimed that `words <= prefixes` but apparently I didn't test that :-/

Comment: Kent's optimization results in a speedup from (on my system) 2.5s to 0.8s.  I can post the modification if you like.

Comment: This helped me learn how a DFS works and how to implement one. Wasn't sure of any way to show appreciation for this other than with a comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

My attempt in Java. It takes about 2 s to read file and build trie, and around 50 ms to solve the puzzle.  I used the dictionary linked in the question (it has a few words that I didn't know exist in English such as fae, ima)

```
0 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.util.Util  - Reading the dictionary
2234 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.util.Util  - Finish reading the dictionary
2234 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: FAM
2234 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: FAME
2234 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: FAMBLE
2234 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: FAE
2234 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: IMA
2234 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: ELI
2234 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: ELM
2234 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: ELB
2234 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: AXIL
2234 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: AXILE
2234 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: AXLE
2234 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: AMI
2234 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: AMIL
2234 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: AMLI
2234 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: AME
2234 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: AMBLE
2234 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: AMBO
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: AES
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: AWL
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: AWE
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: AWEST
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: AWA
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: MIX
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: MIL
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: MILE
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: MILO
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: MAX
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: MAE
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: MAW
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: MEW
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: MEWL
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: MES
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: MESA
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: MWA
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: MWA
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: LIE
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: LIM
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: LIMA
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: LIMAX
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: LIME
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: LIMES
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: LIMB
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: LIMBO
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: LIMBU
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: LEI
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: LEO
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: LOB
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: LOX
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: OIME
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: OIL
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: OLE
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: OLM
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: EMIL
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: EMBOLE
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: EMBOX
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: EAST
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: WAF
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: WAX
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: WAME
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: WAMBLE
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: WAE
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: WEA
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: WEAM
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: WEM
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: WEA
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: WES
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: WEST
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: WAE
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: WAS
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: WASE
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: WAST
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: BLEO
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: BLO
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: BOIL
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: BOLE
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: BUT
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: AES
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: AWA
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: AWL
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: AWE
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: AWEST
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: ASE
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: ASEM
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: AST
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: SEA
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: SEAX
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: SEAM
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: SEMI
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: SEMBLE
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: SEW
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: SEA
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: SWA
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: SWAM
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: SWAMI
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: SWA
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: SAW
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: SAWT
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: STU
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: STUB
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: TWA
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: TWAE
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: TWA
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: TWAE
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: TWAS
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: TUB
2250 [main] INFO gineer.bogglesolver.Solver  - Found: TUX
```

Source code consists of 6 classes.  I'll post them below (if this is not the right practice on StackOverflow, please tell me).

#### gineer.bogglesolver.Main

```
package gineer.bogglesolver;

import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Main
{
    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Main.class);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BasicConfigurator.configure();

        Solver solver = new Solver(4,
                        "FXIE" +
                        "AMLO" +
                        "EWBX" +
                        "ASTU");
        solver.solve();

    }
}
```

#### gineer.bogglesolver.Solver

```
package gineer.bogglesolver;

import gineer.bogglesolver.trie.Trie;
import gineer.bogglesolver.util.Constants;
import gineer.bogglesolver.util.Util;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Solver
{
    private char[] puzzle;
    private int maxSize;

    private boolean[] used;
    private StringBuilder stringSoFar;

    private boolean[][] matrix;
    private Trie trie;

    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Solver.class);

    public Solver(int size, String puzzle)
    {
        trie = Util.getTrie(size);
        matrix = Util.connectivityMatrix(size);

        maxSize = size * size;
        stringSoFar = new StringBuilder(maxSize);
        used = new boolean[maxSize];

        if (puzzle.length() == maxSize)
        {
            this.puzzle = puzzle.toCharArray();
        }
        else
        {
            logger.error("The puzzle size does not match the size specified: " + puzzle.length());
            this.puzzle = puzzle.substring(0, maxSize).toCharArray();
        }
    }

    public void solve()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++)
        {
            traverseAt(i);
        }
    }

    private void traverseAt(int origin)
    {
        stringSoFar.append(puzzle[origin]);
        used[origin] = true;

        //Check if we have a valid word
        if ((stringSoFar.length() >= Constants.MINIMUM_WORD_LENGTH) && (trie.containKey(stringSoFar.toString())))
        {
            logger.info("Found: " + stringSoFar.toString());
        }

        //Find where to go next
        for (int destination = 0; destination < maxSize; destination++)
        {
            if (matrix[origin][destination] && !used[destination] && trie.containPrefix(stringSoFar.toString() + puzzle[destination]))
            {
                traverseAt(destination);
            }
        }

        used[origin] = false;
        stringSoFar.deleteCharAt(stringSoFar.length() - 1);
    }

}
```

#### gineer.bogglesolver.trie.Node

```
package gineer.bogglesolver.trie;

import gineer.bogglesolver.util.Constants;

class Node
{
    Node[] children;
    boolean isKey;

    public Node()
    {
        isKey = false;
        children = new Node[Constants.NUMBER_LETTERS_IN_ALPHABET];
    }

    public Node(boolean key)
    {
        isKey = key;
        children = new Node[Constants.NUMBER_LETTERS_IN_ALPHABET];
    }

    /**
     Method to insert a string to Node and its children

     @param key the string to insert (the string is assumed to be uppercase)
     @return true if the node or one of its children is changed, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean insert(String key)
    {
        //If the key is empty, this node is a key
        if (key.length() == 0)
        {
            if (isKey)
                return false;
            else
            {
                isKey = true;
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
        {//otherwise, insert in one of its child

            int childNodePosition = key.charAt(0) - Constants.LETTER_A;
            if (children[childNodePosition] == null)
            {
                children[childNodePosition] = new Node();
                children[childNodePosition].insert(key.substring(1));
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return children[childNodePosition].insert(key.substring(1));
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     Returns whether key is a valid prefix for certain key in this trie.
     For example: if key "hello" is in this trie, tests with all prefixes "hel", "hell", "hello" return true

     @param prefix the prefix to check
     @return true if the prefix is valid, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean containPrefix(String prefix)
    {
        //If the prefix is empty, return true
        if (prefix.length() == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {//otherwise, check in one of its child
            int childNodePosition = prefix.charAt(0) - Constants.LETTER_A;
            return children[childNodePosition] != null && children[childNodePosition].containPrefix(prefix.substring(1));
        }
    }

    /**
     Returns whether key is a valid key in this trie.
     For example: if key "hello" is in this trie, tests with all prefixes "hel", "hell" return false

     @param key the key to check
     @return true if the key is valid, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean containKey(String key)
    {
        //If the prefix is empty, return true
        if (key.length() == 0)
        {
            return isKey;
        }
        else
        {//otherwise, check in one of its child
            int childNodePosition = key.charAt(0) - Constants.LETTER_A;
            return children[childNodePosition] != null && children[childNodePosition].containKey(key.substring(1));
        }
    }

    public boolean isKey()
    {
        return isKey;
    }

    public void setKey(boolean key)
    {
        isKey = key;
    }
}
```

#### gineer.bogglesolver.trie.Trie

```
package gineer.bogglesolver.trie;

public class Trie
{
    Node root;

    public Trie()
    {
        this.root = new Node();
    }

    /**
     Method to insert a string to Node and its children

     @param key the string to insert (the string is assumed to be uppercase)
     @return true if the node or one of its children is changed, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean insert(String key)
    {
        return root.insert(key.toUpperCase());
    }

    /**
     Returns whether key is a valid prefix for certain key in this trie.
     For example: if key "hello" is in this trie, tests with all prefixes "hel", "hell", "hello" return true

     @param prefix the prefix to check
     @return true if the prefix is valid, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean containPrefix(String prefix)
    {
        return root.containPrefix(prefix.toUpperCase());
    }

    /**
     Returns whether key is a valid key in this trie.
     For example: if key "hello" is in this trie, tests with all prefixes "hel", "hell" return false

     @param key the key to check
     @return true if the key is valid, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean containKey(String key)
    {
        return root.containKey(key.toUpperCase());
    }


}
```

#### gineer.bogglesolver.util.Constants

```
package gineer.bogglesolver.util;

public class Constants
{

    public static final int NUMBER_LETTERS_IN_ALPHABET = 26;
    public static final char LETTER_A = 'A';
    public static final int MINIMUM_WORD_LENGTH = 3;
    public static final int DEFAULT_PUZZLE_SIZE = 4;
}
```

#### gineer.bogglesolver.util.Util

```
package gineer.bogglesolver.util;

import gineer.bogglesolver.trie.Trie;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Util
{
    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Util.class);
    private static Trie trie;
    private static int size = Constants.DEFAULT_PUZZLE_SIZE;

    /**
     Returns the trie built from the dictionary.  The size is used to eliminate words that are too long.

     @param size the size of puzzle.  The maximum lenght of words in the returned trie is (size * size)
     @return the trie that can be used for puzzle of that size
     */
    public static Trie getTrie(int size)
    {
        if ((trie != null) && size == Util.size)
            return trie;

        trie = new Trie();
        Util.size = size;

        logger.info("Reading the dictionary");
        final File file = new File("dictionary.txt");
        try
        {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
            final int maxSize = size * size;
            while (scanner.hasNext())
            {
                String line = scanner.nextLine().replaceAll("[^\\p{Alpha}]", "");

                if (line.length() <= maxSize)
                    trie.insert(line);
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            logger.error("Cannot open file", e);
        }

        logger.info("Finish reading the dictionary");
        return trie;
    }

    static boolean[] connectivityRow(int x, int y, int size)
    {
        boolean[] squares = new boolean[size * size];
        for (int offsetX = -1; offsetX <= 1; offsetX++)
        {
            for (int offsetY = -1; offsetY <= 1; offsetY++)
            {
                final int calX = x + offsetX;
                final int calY = y + offsetY;
                if ((calX >= 0) && (calX < size) && (calY >= 0) && (calY < size))
                    squares[calY * size + calX] = true;
            }
        }

        squares[y * size + x] = false;//the current x, y is false

        return squares;
    }

    /**
     Returns the matrix of connectivity between two points.  Point i can go to point j iff matrix[i][j] is true
     Square (x, y) is equivalent to point (size * y + x).  For example, square (1,1) is point 5 in a puzzle of size 4

     @param size the size of the puzzle
     @return the connectivity matrix
     */
    public static boolean[][] connectivityMatrix(int size)
    {
        boolean[][] matrix = new boolean[size * size][];
        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < size; y++)
            {
                matrix[y * size + x] = connectivityRow(x, y, size);
            }
        }
        return matrix;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was comparing my output with outputs from other StackOverflowers, and it seems Adam, John, and rvarcher's outputs were missing some words.  For example, "Mwa" is in the dictionary (yeah!), but it is not returned in outputs from Adam, John, and rvarcher.  It is returned twice in Paolo's PHP link.

Comment: I tried this one by copy pasting it. It says "Reading..." and "Finish reading...", but nothing appears after that. No matches are displayed.

Answer (score 23):

I think you will probably spend most of your time trying to match words that can't possibly be built by your letter grid. So, the first thing I would do is try to speed up that step and that should get you most of the way there.

For this, I would re-express the grid as a table of possible "moves" that you index by the letter-transition you are looking at.

Start by assigning each letter a number from your entire alphabet (A=0, B=1, C=2, ... and so forth).

Let's take this example:

```
h b c d
e e g h
l l k l
m o f p
```

And for now, lets use the alphabet of the letters we have (usually you'd probably want to use the same whole alphabet every time):

```
 b | c | d | e | f | g | h | k | l | m |  o |  p
---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+----
 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11
```

Then you make a 2D boolean array that tells whether you have a certain letter transition available:

```
     |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11  <- from letter
     |  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  k  l  m  o  p
-----+--------------------------------------
 0 b |     T     T     T  T     
 1 c |  T     T  T     T  T
 2 d |     T           T  T
 3 e |  T  T     T     T  T  T  T
 4 f |                       T  T     T  T
 5 g |  T  T  T  T        T  T  T
 6 h |  T  T  T  T     T     T  T
 7 k |           T  T  T  T     T     T  T
 8 l |           T  T  T  T  T  T  T  T  T
 9 m |                          T     T
10 o |              T        T  T  T
11 p |              T        T  T
 ^
 to letter
```

Now go through your word list and convert the words to transitions:

```
hello (6, 3, 8, 8, 10):
6 -> 3, 3 -> 8, 8 -> 8, 8 -> 10
```

Then check if these transitions are allowed by looking them up in your table:

```
[6][ 3] : T
[3][ 8] : T
[8][ 8] : T
[8][10] : T
```

If they are all allowed, there's a chance that this word might be found.

For example the word "helmet" can be ruled out on the 4th transition (m to e: helMEt), since that entry in your table is false.

And the word hamster can be ruled out, since the first (h to a) transition is not allowed (doesn't even exist in your table).

Now, for the probably very few remaining words that you didn't eliminate, try to actually find them in the grid the way you're doing it now or as suggested in some of the other answers here. This is to avoid false positives that result from jumps between identical letters in your grid. For example the word "help" is allowed by the table, but not by the grid.

**Some further performance improvement tips on this idea:**

1. Instead of using a 2D array, use a 1D array and simply compute the index of the second letter yourself. So, instead of a 12x12 array like above, make a 1D array of length 144. If you then always use the same alphabet (i.e. a 26x26 = 676x1 array for the standard english alphabet), even if not all letters show up in your grid, you can pre-compute the indices into this 1D array that you need to test to match your dictionary words. For example, the indices for 'hello' in the example above would be

   ```
   hello (6, 3, 8, 8, 10):
   42 (from 6 + 3x12), 99, 104, 128
   -> "hello" will be stored as 42, 99, 104, 128 in the dictionary
   ```
2. Extend the idea to a 3D table (expressed as a 1D array), i.e. all allowed 3-letter combinations. That way you can eliminate even more words immediately and you reduce the number of array lookups for each word by 1: For 'hello', you only need 3 array lookups: hel, ell, llo. It will be very quick to build this table, by the way, as there are only 400 possible 3-letter-moves in your grid.
3. Pre-compute the indices of the moves in your grid that you need to include in your table. For the example above, you need to set the following entries to 'True':

   ```
   (0,0) (0,1) -> here: h, b : [6][0]
   (0,0) (1,0) -> here: h, e : [6][3]
   (0,0) (1,1) -> here: h, e : [6][3]
   (0,1) (0,0) -> here: b, h : [0][6]
   (0,1) (0,2) -> here: b, c : [0][1]
   .
   :
   ```
4. Also represent your game grid in a 1-D array with 16 entries and have the table pre-computed in 3. contain the indices into this array.

I'm sure if you use this approach you can get your code to run insanely fast, if you have the dictionary pre-computed and already loaded into memory.

BTW: Another nice thing to do, if you are building a game, is to run these sort of things immediately in the background. Start generating and solving the first game while the user is still looking at the title screen on your app and getting his finger into position to press "Play". Then generate and solve the next game as the user plays the previous one. That should give you a lot of time to run your code.

(I like this problem, so I'll probably be tempted to implement my proposal in Java sometime in the next days to see how it would actually perform... I'll post the code here once I do.)

**UPDATE:**

Ok, I had some time today and implemented this idea in Java:

```java
class DictionaryEntry {
  public int[] letters;
  public int[] triplets;
}

class BoggleSolver {

  // Constants
  final int ALPHABET_SIZE = 5;  // up to 2^5 = 32 letters
  final int BOARD_SIZE    = 4;  // 4x4 board
  final int[] moves = {-BOARD_SIZE-1, -BOARD_SIZE, -BOARD_SIZE+1, 
                                  -1,                         +1,
                       +BOARD_SIZE-1, +BOARD_SIZE, +BOARD_SIZE+1};


  // Technically constant (calculated here for flexibility, but should be fixed)
  DictionaryEntry[] dictionary; // Processed word list
  int maxWordLength = 0;
  int[] boardTripletIndices; // List of all 3-letter moves in board coordinates

  DictionaryEntry[] buildDictionary(String fileName) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    String word = fileReader.readLine();
    ArrayList<DictionaryEntry> result = new ArrayList<DictionaryEntry>();
    while (word!=null) {
      if (word.length()>=3) {
        word = word.toUpperCase();
        if (word.length()>maxWordLength) maxWordLength = word.length();
        DictionaryEntry entry = new DictionaryEntry();
        entry.letters  = new int[word.length()  ];
        entry.triplets = new int[word.length()-2];
        int i=0;
        for (char letter: word.toCharArray()) {
          entry.letters[i] = (byte) letter - 65; // Convert ASCII to 0..25
          if (i>=2)
            entry.triplets[i-2] = (((entry.letters[i-2]  << ALPHABET_SIZE) +
                                     entry.letters[i-1]) << ALPHABET_SIZE) +
                                     entry.letters[i];
          i++;
        }
        result.add(entry);
      }
      word = fileReader.readLine();
    }
    return result.toArray(new DictionaryEntry[result.size()]);
  }

  boolean isWrap(int a, int b) { // Checks if move a->b wraps board edge (like 3->4)
    return Math.abs(a%BOARD_SIZE-b%BOARD_SIZE)>1;
  }

  int[] buildTripletIndices() {
    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int a=0; a<BOARD_SIZE*BOARD_SIZE; a++)
      for (int bm: moves) {
        int b=a+bm;
        if ((b>=0) && (b<board.length) && !isWrap(a, b))
          for (int cm: moves) {
            int c=b+cm;
            if ((c>=0) && (c<board.length) && (c!=a) && !isWrap(b, c)) {
              result.add(a);
              result.add(b);
              result.add(c);
            }
          }
      }
    int[] result2 = new int[result.size()];
    int i=0;
    for (Integer r: result) result2[i++] = r;
    return result2;
  }


  // Variables that depend on the actual game layout
  int[] board = new int[BOARD_SIZE*BOARD_SIZE]; // Letters in board
  boolean[] possibleTriplets = new boolean[1 << (ALPHABET_SIZE*3)];

  DictionaryEntry[] candidateWords;
  int candidateCount;

  int[] usedBoardPositions;

  DictionaryEntry[] foundWords;
  int foundCount;

  void initializeBoard(String[] letters) {
    for (int row=0; row<BOARD_SIZE; row++)
      for (int col=0; col<BOARD_SIZE; col++)
        board[row*BOARD_SIZE + col] = (byte) letters[row].charAt(col) - 65;
  }

  void setPossibleTriplets() {
    Arrays.fill(possibleTriplets, false); // Reset list
    int i=0;
    while (i<boardTripletIndices.length) {
      int triplet = (((board[boardTripletIndices[i++]]  << ALPHABET_SIZE) +
                       board[boardTripletIndices[i++]]) << ALPHABET_SIZE) +
                       board[boardTripletIndices[i++]];
      possibleTriplets[triplet] = true; 
    }
  }

  void checkWordTriplets() {
    candidateCount = 0;
    for (DictionaryEntry entry: dictionary) {
      boolean ok = true;
      int len = entry.triplets.length;
      for (int t=0; (t<len) && ok; t++)
        ok = possibleTriplets[entry.triplets[t]];
      if (ok) candidateWords[candidateCount++] = entry;
    }
  }

  void checkWords() { // Can probably be optimized a lot
    foundCount = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<candidateCount; i++) {
      DictionaryEntry candidate = candidateWords[i];
      for (int j=0; j<board.length; j++)
        if (board[j]==candidate.letters[0]) { 
          usedBoardPositions[0] = j;
          if (checkNextLetters(candidate, 1, j)) {
            foundWords[foundCount++] = candidate;
            break;
          }
        }
    }
  }

  boolean checkNextLetters(DictionaryEntry candidate, int letter, int pos) {
    if (letter==candidate.letters.length) return true;
    int match = candidate.letters[letter];
    for (int move: moves) {
      int next=pos+move;
      if ((next>=0) && (next<board.length) && (board[next]==match) && !isWrap(pos, next)) {
        boolean ok = true;
        for (int i=0; (i<letter) && ok; i++)
          ok = usedBoardPositions[i]!=next;
        if (ok) {
          usedBoardPositions[letter] = next;
          if (checkNextLetters(candidate, letter+1, next)) return true;
        }
      }
    }   
    return false;
  }


  // Just some helper functions
  String formatTime(long start, long end, long repetitions) {
    long time = (end-start)/repetitions;
    return time/1000000 + "." + (time/100000) % 10 + "" + (time/10000) % 10 + "ms";
  }

  String getWord(DictionaryEntry entry) {
    char[] result = new char[entry.letters.length];
    int i=0;
    for (int letter: entry.letters)
      result[i++] = (char) (letter+97);
    return new String(result);
  }

  void run() throws IOException {
    long start = System.nanoTime();

    // The following can be pre-computed and should be replaced by constants
    dictionary = buildDictionary("C:/TWL06.txt");
    boardTripletIndices = buildTripletIndices();
    long precomputed = System.nanoTime();


    // The following only needs to run once at the beginning of the program
    candidateWords     = new DictionaryEntry[dictionary.length]; // WAAAY too generous
    foundWords         = new DictionaryEntry[dictionary.length]; // WAAAY too generous
    usedBoardPositions = new int[maxWordLength];
    long initialized = System.nanoTime(); 

    for (int n=1; n<=100; n++) {
      // The following needs to run again for every new board
      initializeBoard(new String[] {"DGHI",
                                    "KLPS",
                                    "YEUT",
                                    "EORN"});
      setPossibleTriplets();
      checkWordTriplets();
      checkWords();
    }
    long solved = System.nanoTime();


    // Print out result and statistics
    System.out.println("Precomputation finished in " + formatTime(start, precomputed, 1)+":");
    System.out.println("  Words in the dictionary: "+dictionary.length);
    System.out.println("  Longest word:            "+maxWordLength+" letters");
    System.out.println("  Number of triplet-moves: "+boardTripletIndices.length/3);
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Initialization finished in " + formatTime(precomputed, initialized, 1));
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Board solved in "+formatTime(initialized, solved, 100)+":");
    System.out.println("  Number of candidates: "+candidateCount);
    System.out.println("  Number of actual words: "+foundCount);
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Words found:");
    int w=0;
    System.out.print("  ");
    for (int i=0; i<foundCount; i++) {
      System.out.print(getWord(foundWords[i]));
      w++;
      if (w==10) {
        w=0;
        System.out.println(); System.out.print("  ");
      } else
        if (i<foundCount-1) System.out.print(", ");
    }
    System.out.println();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    new BoggleSolver().run();
  }
}
```

**Here are some results:**

For the grid from the picture posted in the original question (DGHI...):

```
Precomputation finished in 239.59ms:
  Words in the dictionary: 178590
  Longest word:            15 letters
  Number of triplet-moves: 408

Initialization finished in 0.22ms

Board solved in 3.70ms:
  Number of candidates: 230
  Number of actual words: 163 

Words found:
  eek, eel, eely, eld, elhi, elk, ern, erupt, erupts, euro
  eye, eyer, ghi, ghis, glee, gley, glue, gluer, gluey, glut
  gluts, hip, hiply, hips, his, hist, kelp, kelps, kep, kepi
  kepis, keps, kept, kern, key, kye, lee, lek, lept, leu
  ley, lunt, lunts, lure, lush, lust, lustre, lye, nus, nut
  nuts, ore, ort, orts, ouph, ouphs, our, oust, out, outre
  outs, oyer, pee, per, pert, phi, phis, pis, pish, plus
  plush, ply, plyer, psi, pst, pul, pule, puler, pun, punt
  punts, pur, pure, puree, purely, pus, push, put, puts, ree
  rely, rep, reply, reps, roe, roue, roup, roups, roust, rout
  routs, rue, rule, ruly, run, runt, runts, rupee, rush, rust
  rut, ruts, ship, shlep, sip, sipe, spue, spun, spur, spurn
  spurt, strep, stroy, stun, stupe, sue, suer, sulk, sulker, sulky
  sun, sup, supe, super, sure, surely, tree, trek, trey, troupe
  troy, true, truly, tule, tun, tup, tups, turn, tush, ups
  urn, uts, yeld, yelk, yelp, yelps, yep, yeps, yore, you
  your, yourn, yous
```

For the letters posted as the example in the original question (FXIE...)

```
Precomputation finished in 239.68ms:
  Words in the dictionary: 178590
  Longest word:            15 letters
  Number of triplet-moves: 408

Initialization finished in 0.21ms

Board solved in 3.69ms:
  Number of candidates: 87
  Number of actual words: 76

Words found:
  amble, ambo, ami, amie, asea, awa, awe, awes, awl, axil
  axile, axle, boil, bole, box, but, buts, east, elm, emboli
  fame, fames, fax, lei, lie, lima, limb, limbo, limbs, lime
  limes, lob, lobs, lox, mae, maes, maw, maws, max, maxi
  mesa, mew, mewl, mews, mil, mile, milo, mix, oil, ole
  sae, saw, sea, seam, semi, sew, stub, swam, swami, tub
  tubs, tux, twa, twae, twaes, twas, uts, wae, waes, wamble
  wame, wames, was, wast, wax, west
```

For the following 5x5-grid:

```
R P R I T
A H H L N
I E T E P
Z R Y S G
O G W E Y
```

it gives this:

```
Precomputation finished in 240.39ms:
  Words in the dictionary: 178590
  Longest word:            15 letters
  Number of triplet-moves: 768

Initialization finished in 0.23ms

Board solved in 3.85ms:
  Number of candidates: 331
  Number of actual words: 240

Words found:
  aero, aery, ahi, air, airt, airth, airts, airy, ear, egest
  elhi, elint, erg, ergo, ester, eth, ether, eye, eyen, eyer
  eyes, eyre, eyrie, gel, gelt, gelts, gen, gent, gentil, gest
  geste, get, gets, gey, gor, gore, gory, grey, greyest, greys
  gyre, gyri, gyro, hae, haet, haets, hair, hairy, hap, harp
  heap, hear, heh, heir, help, helps, hen, hent, hep, her
  hero, hes, hest, het, hetero, heth, hets, hey, hie, hilt
  hilts, hin, hint, hire, hit, inlet, inlets, ire, leg, leges
  legs, lehr, lent, les, lest, let, lethe, lets, ley, leys
  lin, line, lines, liney, lint, lit, neg, negs, nest, nester
  net, nether, nets, nil, nit, ogre, ore, orgy, ort, orts
  pah, pair, par, peg, pegs, peh, pelt, pelter, peltry, pelts
  pen, pent, pes, pest, pester, pesty, pet, peter, pets, phi
  philter, philtre, phiz, pht, print, pst, rah, rai, rap, raphe
  raphes, reap, rear, rei, ret, rete, rets, rhaphe, rhaphes, rhea
  ria, rile, riles, riley, rin, rye, ryes, seg, sel, sen
  sent, senti, set, sew, spelt, spelter, spent, splent, spline, splint
  split, stent, step, stey, stria, striae, sty, stye, tea, tear
  teg, tegs, tel, ten, tent, thae, the, their, then, these
  thesp, they, thin, thine, thir, thirl, til, tile, tiles, tilt
  tilter, tilth, tilts, tin, tine, tines, tirl, trey, treys, trog
  try, tye, tyer, tyes, tyre, tyro, west, wester, wry, wryest
  wye, wyes, wyte, wytes, yea, yeah, year, yeh, yelp, yelps
  yen, yep, yeps, yes, yester, yet, yew, yews, zero, zori
```

For this I used the [TWL06 Tournament Scrabble Word List](http://www.isc.ro/lists/twl06.zip), since the link in the original question no longer works. This file is 1.85MB, so it's a little bit shorter. And the `buildDictionary` function throws out all words with less than 3 letters.

Here are a couple of observations about the performance of this:

- It's about 10 times slower than the reported performance of Victor Nicollet's OCaml implementation. Whether this is caused by the different algorithm, the shorter dictionary he used, the fact that his code is compiled and mine runs in a Java virtual machine, or the performance of our computers (mine is an Intel Q6600 @ 2.4MHz running WinXP), I don't know. But it's much faster than the results for the other implementations quoted at the end of the original question. So, whether this algorithm is superior to the trie dictionary or not, I don't know at this point.
- The table method used in `checkWordTriplets()` yields a very good approximation to the actual answers. Only 1 in 3-5 words passed by it will fail the `checkWords()` test (See *number of candidates* vs. *number of actual words* above).
- Something you can't see above: The `checkWordTriplets()` function takes about 3.65ms and is therefore fully dominant in the search process. The `checkWords()` function takes up pretty much the remaining 0.05-0.20 ms.
- The execution time of the `checkWordTriplets()` function depends linearly on the dictionary size and is virtually **independent of board size!**
- The execution time of `checkWords()` depends on the board size and the number of words not ruled out by `checkWordTriplets()`.
- The `checkWords()` implementation above is the dumbest first version I came up with. It is basically not optimized at all. But compared to `checkWordTriplets()` it is irrelevant for the total performance of the application, so I didn't worry about it. **But**, if the board size gets bigger, this function will get slower and slower and will eventually start to matter. Then, it would need to be optimized as well.
- One nice thing about this code is its flexibility:

  - You can easily change the board size: Update line 10 and the String array passed to `initializeBoard()`.
  - It can support larger/different alphabets and can handle things like treating 'Qu' as one letter without any performance overhead. To do this, one would need to update line 9 and the couple of places where characters are converted to numbers (currently simply by subtracting 65 from the ASCII value)

Ok, but I think by now this post is waaaay long enough. I can definitely answer any questions you might have, but let's move that to the comments.

Comment: Nice answer. I'd like to see your implementation in Java.

Comment: @MikkoP Done! :) Took about 3 hours and 220 lines of code. Good way to pass an afternoon. Let me know if you have any questions about how it works... :)

Comment: Thanks for posting the code! I tried it with my own dictionary after I had added the missing imports. I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException on the line `ok = possibleTriplets[entry.triplets[t]];`. hmm?

Comment: @MikkoP This code is currently written to assume the dictionary to only contain upper case letters A-Z. The crux is in line 34: `entry.letters[i] = (byte) letter - 65;` It simply takes the ASCII value and subtracts 65 ("A"). If you have Umlauts or lower-case letters in your dictionary, this will give values greater than 31, which aren't planned for by the setting of the alphabet size in line 9. To support other letters, you would have to expand this line to map them into the range allowed by the alphabet size.

Comment: @MikkoP The same concern applies to the 3rd line in the `initializeBoard()` function, by the way.

Comment: Ah, okay. The words are lowercase and contain umlauts (å, ä, ö).

Comment: You'd need to write yourself a little function of the form `int charToInt(char letter)` (maybe just a table lookup) that spits out values from 0 to less than 2^ALPHABET_SIZE (which you can increase) that are unique for each distinct letter (e.g. a=A=0, b=B=1, ...). Use this function in the `buildDictionary` and the `initializeBoard` methods instead of the `(byte) letter - 65`. Then, you also need to adjust the `getWord` method by replacing the `(char) (letter+97)` with the corresponding inverse function of your `int charToInt(char letter)` routine. Then everything should work as expected.

Comment: did you forget to add the letter (i)?  
b | c | d | e | f | g | h | k | l | m |  o |  p
or am i not understanding your logic?

Comment: @AlexanderN You are probably understanding the logic correctly. I made a mistake copying letter grid... Sorry... (fixed)

Answer (score 19):

Surprisingly, no one attempted a PHP version of this.

This is a working PHP version of John Fouhy's Python solution.

Although I took some pointers from everyone else's answers, this is mostly copied from John.

```
$boggle = "fxie
           amlo
           ewbx
           astu";

$alphabet = str_split(str_replace(array("\n", " ", "\r"), "", strtolower($boggle)));
$rows = array_map('trim', explode("\n", $boggle));
$dictionary = file("C:/dict.txt");
$prefixes = array(''=>'');
$words = array();
$regex = '/[' . implode('', $alphabet) . ']{3,}$/S';
foreach($dictionary as $k=>$value) {
    $value = trim(strtolower($value));
    $length = strlen($value);
    if(preg_match($regex, $value)) {
        for($x = 0; $x < $length; $x++) {
            $letter = substr($value, 0, $x+1);
            if($letter == $value) {
                $words[$value] = 1;
            } else {
                $prefixes[$letter] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

$graph = array();
$chardict = array();
$positions = array();
$c = count($rows);
for($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
    $l = strlen($rows[$i]);
    for($j = 0; $j < $l; $j++) {
        $chardict[$i.','.$j] = $rows[$i][$j];
        $children = array();
        $pos = array(-1,0,1);
        foreach($pos as $z) {
            $xCoord = $z + $i;
            if($xCoord < 0 || $xCoord >= count($rows)) {
                continue;
            }
            $len = strlen($rows[0]);
            foreach($pos as $w) {
                $yCoord = $j + $w;
                if(($yCoord < 0 || $yCoord >= $len) || ($z == 0 && $w == 0)) {
                    continue;
                }
                $children[] = array($xCoord, $yCoord);
            }
        }
        $graph['None'][] = array($i, $j);
        $graph[$i.','.$j] = $children;
    }
}

function to_word($chardict, $prefix) {
    $word = array();
    foreach($prefix as $v) {
        $word[] = $chardict[$v[0].','.$v[1]];
    }
    return implode("", $word);
}

function find_words($graph, $chardict, $position, $prefix, $prefixes, &$results, $words) {
    $word = to_word($chardict, $prefix);
    if(!isset($prefixes[$word])) return false;

    if(isset($words[$word])) {
        $results[] = $word;
    }

    foreach($graph[$position] as $child) {
        if(!in_array($child, $prefix)) {
            $newprefix = $prefix;
            $newprefix[] = $child;
            find_words($graph, $chardict, $child[0].','.$child[1], $newprefix, $prefixes, $results, $words);
        }
    }
}

$solution = array();
find_words($graph, $chardict, 'None', array(), $prefixes, $solution);
print_r($solution);
```

Here is a [live link](http://www.rootspot.com/stackoverflow/boggle.php) if you want to try it out. Although it takes ~2s in my local machine, it takes ~5s on my webserver. In either case, it is not very fast.  Still, though, it is quite hideous so I can imagine the time can be reduced significantly. Any pointers on how to accomplish that would be appreciated. PHP's lack of tuples made the coordinates weird to work with and my inability to comprehend just what the hell is going on didn't help at all.

**EDIT**: A few fixes make it take less than 1s locally.

Comment: +1 @ "and my inability to comprehend just what the hell is going on didn't help at all." lol. I love honesty!

Comment: I don't know PHP, but the first thing I'd try is hoisting '/[' . implode('', $alphabet) . ']{3,}$/' out of the loop. That is, set a variable to that and use the variable instead inside the loop.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that PHP keeps a per-thread global cache of compiled regular expressions, but I'll try that anyways.

Comment: I followed the advice in this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209906/compile-regex-in-php) and added the S flag to the preg_match, it reduced the time by ~0.1s, not that much but I'll take it. :)

Comment: Paolo, maybe I'm wrong about PHP, but I'd assume that, as in other languages, that cache maps from regexes in their string form to regexes in their compiled form. But you have an expression to evaluate just to get to the string form, first. The PHP compiler would have to figure out that the expression is invariant if it's to safely skip reevaluating it.

Comment: Not the case with PHP, Darius.

Comment: nsis
oczx
ylty
aerh
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 58720256 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 48 bytes) in /home/pbysh/www/stackoverflow/boggle.php on line 23

Comment: @Paolo did you use the letters nsis oczx ylty aerh? Tried again and the error persists.

Comment: @Daniel: You have to put newlines every 4 characters. nsis\n
oczx\n
ylty\n
aerh\n

Comment: @Paolo: I did that. I used other letters and works fine. But those I get this error.

Comment: @Daniel: Apparently it's my web server. It doesn't happen when I run locally. Shrug. Don't really feel like hunting it down.

Comment: What should be set as the 7. parameter in the find_words function in the end?

Comment: @Paolo: I know it's been a while since you last posted on this question, but I'm wondering if this is all of the code, as I tried and just keep getting empty result set.

Comment: @Nikola: Did you point the script to the location of your own dictionary file?

Comment: @PaoloBergantino: yes, sure I did (it has one word per line), and I did enter letters which should definitely match the search. I went and debuged the code and as it seems that the `if(isset($words[$word]))` doesn't go through as I always get an empty `results` array. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: MikkoP you can get @words from above..so just pass 7 parameters $words. Its solve

Answer (score 16):

Not interested in VB? :) I couldn't resist. I've solved this differently than many of the solutions presented here.

My times are:

- Loading the dictionary and word prefixes into a hashtable: .5 to 1 seconds.
- Finding the words: averaging under 10 milliseconds.

EDIT: Dictionary load times on the web host server are running about 1 to 1.5 seconds longer than my home computer.

I don't know how badly the times will deteriorate with a load on the server.

I wrote my solution as a web page in .Net. [myvrad.com/boggle](http://www.myvrad.com/boggle/default.aspx)

I'm using the dictionary referenced in the original question.

Letters are not reused in a word. Only words 3 characters or longer are found.

I'm using a hashtable of all unique word prefixes and words instead of a trie. I didn't know about trie's so I learned something there. The idea of creating a list of prefixes of words in addition to the complete words is what finally got my times down to a respectable number.

Read the code comments for additional details.

Here's the code:

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.IO

Partial Class boggle_Default

    'Bob Archer, 4/15/2009

    'To avoid using a 2 dimensional array in VB I'm not using typical X,Y
    'coordinate iteration to find paths.
    '
    'I have locked the code into a 4 by 4 grid laid out like so:
    ' abcd
    ' efgh
    ' ijkl
    ' mnop
    ' 
    'To find paths the code starts with a letter from a to p then
    'explores the paths available around it. If a neighboring letter
    'already exists in the path then we don't go there.
    '
    'Neighboring letters (grid points) are hard coded into
    'a Generic.Dictionary below.



    'Paths is a list of only valid Paths found. 
    'If a word prefix or word is not found the path is not
    'added and extending that path is terminated.
    Dim Paths As New Generic.List(Of String)

    'NeighborsOf. The keys are the letters a to p.
    'The value is a string of letters representing neighboring letters.
    'The string of neighboring letters is split and iterated later.
    Dim NeigborsOf As New Generic.Dictionary(Of String, String)

    'BoggleLetters. The keys are mapped to the lettered grid of a to p.
    'The values are what the user inputs on the page.
    Dim BoggleLetters As New Generic.Dictionary(Of String, String)

    'Used to store last postition of path. This will be a letter
    'from a to p.
    Dim LastPositionOfPath As String = ""

    'I found a HashTable was by far faster than a Generic.Dictionary 
    ' - about 10 times faster. This stores prefixes of words and words.
    'I determined 792773 was the number of words and unique prefixes that
    'will be generated from the dictionary file. This is a max number and
    'the final hashtable will not have that many.
    Dim HashTableOfPrefixesAndWords As New Hashtable(792773)

    'Stores words that are found.
    Dim FoundWords As New Generic.List(Of String)

    'Just to validate what the user enters in the grid.
    Dim ErrorFoundWithSubmittedLetters As Boolean = False

    Public Sub BuildAndTestPathsAndFindWords(ByVal ThisPath As String)
        'Word is the word correlating to the ThisPath parameter.
        'This path would be a series of letters from a to p.
        Dim Word As String = ""

        'The path is iterated through and a word based on the actual
        'letters in the Boggle grid is assembled.
        For i As Integer = 0 To ThisPath.Length - 1
            Word += Me.BoggleLetters(ThisPath.Substring(i, 1))
        Next

        'If my hashtable of word prefixes and words doesn't contain this Word
        'Then this isn't a word and any further extension of ThisPath will not
        'yield any words either. So exit sub to terminate exploring this path.
        If Not HashTableOfPrefixesAndWords.ContainsKey(Word) Then Exit Sub

        'The value of my hashtable is a boolean representing if the key if a word (true) or
        'just a prefix (false). If true and at least 3 letters long then yay! word found.
        If HashTableOfPrefixesAndWords(Word) AndAlso Word.Length > 2 Then Me.FoundWords.Add(Word)

        'If my List of Paths doesn't contain ThisPath then add it.
        'Remember only valid paths will make it this far. Paths not found
        'in the HashTableOfPrefixesAndWords cause this sub to exit above.
        If Not Paths.Contains(ThisPath) Then Paths.Add(ThisPath)

        'Examine the last letter of ThisPath. We are looking to extend the path
        'to our neighboring letters if any are still available.
        LastPositionOfPath = ThisPath.Substring(ThisPath.Length - 1, 1)

        'Loop through my list of neighboring letters (representing grid points).
        For Each Neighbor As String In Me.NeigborsOf(LastPositionOfPath).ToCharArray()
            'If I find a neighboring grid point that I haven't already used
            'in ThisPath then extend ThisPath and feed the new path into
            'this recursive function. (see recursive.)
            If Not ThisPath.Contains(Neighbor) Then Me.BuildAndTestPathsAndFindWords(ThisPath & Neighbor)
        Next
    End Sub

    Protected Sub ButtonBoggle_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonBoggle.Click

        'User has entered the 16 letters and clicked the go button.

        'Set up my Generic.Dictionary of grid points, I'm using letters a to p -
        'not an x,y grid system.  The values are neighboring points.
        NeigborsOf.Add("a", "bfe")
        NeigborsOf.Add("b", "cgfea")
        NeigborsOf.Add("c", "dhgfb")
        NeigborsOf.Add("d", "hgc")
        NeigborsOf.Add("e", "abfji")
        NeigborsOf.Add("f", "abcgkjie")
        NeigborsOf.Add("g", "bcdhlkjf")
        NeigborsOf.Add("h", "cdlkg")
        NeigborsOf.Add("i", "efjnm")
        NeigborsOf.Add("j", "efgkonmi")
        NeigborsOf.Add("k", "fghlponj")
        NeigborsOf.Add("l", "ghpok")
        NeigborsOf.Add("m", "ijn")
        NeigborsOf.Add("n", "ijkom")
        NeigborsOf.Add("o", "jklpn")
        NeigborsOf.Add("p", "klo")

        'Retrieve letters the user entered.
        BoggleLetters.Add("a", Me.TextBox1.Text.ToLower.Trim())
        BoggleLetters.Add("b", Me.TextBox2.Text.ToLower.Trim())
        BoggleLetters.Add("c", Me.TextBox3.Text.ToLower.Trim())
        BoggleLetters.Add("d", Me.TextBox4.Text.ToLower.Trim())
        BoggleLetters.Add("e", Me.TextBox5.Text.ToLower.Trim())
        BoggleLetters.Add("f", Me.TextBox6.Text.ToLower.Trim())
        BoggleLetters.Add("g", Me.TextBox7.Text.ToLower.Trim())
        BoggleLetters.Add("h", Me.TextBox8.Text.ToLower.Trim())
        BoggleLetters.Add("i", Me.TextBox9.Text.ToLower.Trim())
        BoggleLetters.Add("j", Me.TextBox10.Text.ToLower.Trim())
        BoggleLetters.Add("k", Me.TextBox11.Text.ToLower.Trim())
        BoggleLetters.Add("l", Me.TextBox12.Text.ToLower.Trim())
        BoggleLetters.Add("m", Me.TextBox13.Text.ToLower.Trim())
        BoggleLetters.Add("n", Me.TextBox14.Text.ToLower.Trim())
        BoggleLetters.Add("o", Me.TextBox15.Text.ToLower.Trim())
        BoggleLetters.Add("p", Me.TextBox16.Text.ToLower.Trim())

        'Validate user entered something with a length of 1 for all 16 textboxes.
        For Each S As String In BoggleLetters.Keys
            If BoggleLetters(S).Length <> 1 Then
                ErrorFoundWithSubmittedLetters = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        'If input is not valid then...
        If ErrorFoundWithSubmittedLetters Then
            'Present error message.
        Else
            'Else assume we have 16 letters to work with and start finding words.
            Dim SB As New StringBuilder

            Dim Time As String = String.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}:{3}", Date.Now.Hour.ToString(), Date.Now.Minute.ToString(), Date.Now.Second.ToString(), Date.Now.Millisecond.ToString())

            Dim NumOfLetters As Integer = 0
            Dim Word As String = ""
            Dim TempWord As String = ""
            Dim Letter As String = ""
            Dim fr As StreamReader = Nothing
            fr = New System.IO.StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("~/boggle/dic.txt"))

            'First fill my hashtable with word prefixes and words.
            'HashTable(PrefixOrWordString, BooleanTrueIfWordFalseIfPrefix)
            While fr.Peek <> -1
                Word = fr.ReadLine.Trim()
                TempWord = ""
                For i As Integer = 0 To Word.Length - 1
                    Letter = Word.Substring(i, 1)
                    'This optimization helped quite a bit. Words in the dictionary that begin
                    'with letters that the user did not enter in the grid shouldn't go in my hashtable.
                    '
                    'I realize most of the solutions went with a Trie. I'd never heard of that before,
                    'which is one of the neat things about SO, seeing how others approach challenges
                    'and learning some best practices.
                    '
                    'However, I didn't code a Trie in my solution. I just have a hashtable with 
                    'all words in the dicitonary file and all possible prefixes for those words.
                    'A Trie might be faster but I'm not coding it now. I'm getting good times with this.
                    If i = 0 AndAlso Not BoggleLetters.ContainsValue(Letter) Then Continue While
                    TempWord += Letter
                    If Not HashTableOfPrefixesAndWords.ContainsKey(TempWord) Then
                        HashTableOfPrefixesAndWords.Add(TempWord, TempWord = Word)
                    End If
                Next
            End While

            SB.Append("Number of Word Prefixes and Words in Hashtable: " & HashTableOfPrefixesAndWords.Count.ToString())
            SB.Append("<br />")

            SB.Append("Loading Dictionary: " & Time & " - " & String.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}:{3}", Date.Now.Hour.ToString(), Date.Now.Minute.ToString(), Date.Now.Second.ToString(), Date.Now.Millisecond.ToString()))
            SB.Append("<br />")

            Time = String.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}:{3}", Date.Now.Hour.ToString(), Date.Now.Minute.ToString(), Date.Now.Second.ToString(), Date.Now.Millisecond.ToString())

            'This starts a path at each point on the grid an builds a path until 
            'the string of letters correlating to the path is not found in the hashtable
            'of word prefixes and words.
            Me.BuildAndTestPathsAndFindWords("a")
            Me.BuildAndTestPathsAndFindWords("b")
            Me.BuildAndTestPathsAndFindWords("c")
            Me.BuildAndTestPathsAndFindWords("d")
            Me.BuildAndTestPathsAndFindWords("e")
            Me.BuildAndTestPathsAndFindWords("f")
            Me.BuildAndTestPathsAndFindWords("g")
            Me.BuildAndTestPathsAndFindWords("h")
            Me.BuildAndTestPathsAndFindWords("i")
            Me.BuildAndTestPathsAndFindWords("j")
            Me.BuildAndTestPathsAndFindWords("k")
            Me.BuildAndTestPathsAndFindWords("l")
            Me.BuildAndTestPathsAndFindWords("m")
            Me.BuildAndTestPathsAndFindWords("n")
            Me.BuildAndTestPathsAndFindWords("o")
            Me.BuildAndTestPathsAndFindWords("p")

            SB.Append("Finding Words: " & Time & " - " & String.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}:{3}", Date.Now.Hour.ToString(), Date.Now.Minute.ToString(), Date.Now.Second.ToString(), Date.Now.Millisecond.ToString()))
            SB.Append("<br />")

            SB.Append("Num of words found: " & FoundWords.Count.ToString())
            SB.Append("<br />")
            SB.Append("<br />")

            FoundWords.Sort()
            SB.Append(String.Join("<br />", FoundWords.ToArray()))

            'Output results.
            Me.LiteralBoggleResults.Text = SB.ToString()
            Me.PanelBoggleResults.Visible = True

        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I'm going to assume here you used the a-p system instead of [x][y] because the latter is rather complex in VB? I spent a day trying to get a 2-way-dynamic array in that once, ie: array( array( 1, "hello"), 1, "hello" , array() ) , still don't know how to do that :P

Comment: In PHP and Perl 2 dim arrays are fun. It can be done in VB but I wouldn't call it a fun process. Dim Arr(, ) As Integer = {{1,1},{0,0}}. The A-P process grew out of me putting myself on the grid and asking, 'where can I go from here?' I know it's a rigid solution but it works here.

Comment: Ohh I like VB.NET... I tried the URL but it did not work.
I had to re-build your code myself as Windows Forms and it works.
Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

As soon as I saw the problem statement, I thought "Trie". But seeing as several other posters made use of that approach, I looked for another approach just to be different. Alas, the Trie approach performs better. I ran Kent's Perl solution on my machine and it took **0.31** seconds to run, after adapting it to use my dictionary file. My own perl implementation required **0.54** seconds to run.

This was my approach:

1. Create a transition hash to model the legal transitions.
2. Iterate through all 16^3 possible three letter combinations.

   - In the loop, exclude illegal transitions and repeat visits to the
     same square. Form all the legal 3-letter sequences and store them in a hash.
3. Then loop through all words in the dictionary.

   - Exclude words that are too long or short
   - Slide a 3-letter window across each word and see if it is among the 3-letter combos from step 2. Exclude words that fail. This eliminates most non-matches.
   - If still not eliminated, use a recursive algorithm to see if the word can be formed by making paths through the puzzle. (This part is slow, but called infrequently.)
4. Print out the words I found.

   I tried 3-letter and 4-letter sequences, but 4-letter sequences slowed the program down.

In my code, I use /usr/share/dict/words for my dictionary. It comes standard on MAC OS X and many Unix systems. You can use another file if you want. To crack a different puzzle, just change the variable @puzzle. This would be easy to adapt for larger matrices. You would just need to change the %transitions hash and %legalTransitions hash.

The strength of this solution is that the code is short, and the data structures simple.

Here is the Perl code (which uses too many global variables, I know):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Time::HiRes  qw{ time };

sub readFile($);
sub findAllPrefixes($);
sub isWordTraceable($);
sub findWordsInPuzzle(@);

my $startTime = time;

# Puzzle to solve

my @puzzle = ( 
    F, X, I, E,
    A, M, L, O,
    E, W, B, X,
    A, S, T, U
);

my $minimumWordLength = 3;
my $maximumPrefixLength = 3; # I tried four and it slowed down.

# Slurp the word list.
my $wordlistFile = "/usr/share/dict/words";

my @words = split(/\n/, uc(readFile($wordlistFile)));
print "Words loaded from word list: " . scalar @words . "\n";

print "Word file load time: " . (time - $startTime) . "\n";
my $postLoad = time;

# Define the legal transitions from one letter position to another. 
# Positions are numbered 0-15.
#     0  1  2  3
#     4  5  6  7
#     8  9 10 11
#    12 13 14 15
my %transitions = ( 
   -1 => [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],
    0 => [1,4,5], 
    1 => [0,2,4,5,6],
    2 => [1,3,5,6,7],
    3 => [2,6,7],
    4 => [0,1,5,8,9],
    5 => [0,1,2,4,6,8,9,10],
    6 => [1,2,3,5,7,9,10,11],
    7 => [2,3,6,10,11],
    8 => [4,5,9,12,13],
    9 => [4,5,6,8,10,12,13,14],
    10 => [5,6,7,9,11,13,14,15],
    11 => [6,7,10,14,15],
    12 => [8,9,13],
    13 => [8,9,10,12,14],
    14 => [9,10,11,13,15],
    15 => [10,11,14]
);

# Convert the transition matrix into a hash for easy access.
my %legalTransitions = ();
foreach my $start (keys %transitions) {
    my $legalRef = $transitions{$start};
    foreach my $stop (@$legalRef) {
        my $index = ($start + 1) * (scalar @puzzle) + ($stop + 1);
        $legalTransitions{$index} = 1;
    }
}

my %prefixesInPuzzle = findAllPrefixes($maximumPrefixLength);

print "Find prefixes time: " . (time - $postLoad) . "\n";
my $postPrefix = time;

my @wordsFoundInPuzzle = findWordsInPuzzle(@words);

print "Find words in puzzle time: " . (time - $postPrefix) . "\n";

print "Unique prefixes found: " . (scalar keys %prefixesInPuzzle) . "\n";
print "Words found (" . (scalar @wordsFoundInPuzzle) . ") :\n    " . join("\n    ", @wordsFoundInPuzzle) . "\n";

print "Total Elapsed time: " . (time - $startTime) . "\n";

###########################################

sub readFile($) {
    my ($filename) = @_;
    my $contents;
    if (-e $filename) {
        # This is magic: it opens and reads a file into a scalar in one line of code. 
        # See http://www.perl.com/pub/a/2003/11/21/slurp.html
        $contents = do { local( @ARGV, $/ ) = $filename ; <> } ; 
    }
    else {
        $contents = '';
    }
    return $contents;
}

# Is it legal to move from the first position to the second? They must be adjacent.
sub isLegalTransition($$) {
    my ($pos1,$pos2) = @_;
    my $index = ($pos1 + 1) * (scalar @puzzle) + ($pos2 + 1);
    return $legalTransitions{$index};
}

# Find all prefixes where $minimumWordLength <= length <= $maxPrefixLength
#
#   $maxPrefixLength ... Maximum length of prefix we will store. Three gives best performance. 
sub findAllPrefixes($) {
    my ($maxPrefixLength) = @_;
    my %prefixes = ();
    my $puzzleSize = scalar @puzzle;

    # Every possible N-letter combination of the letters in the puzzle 
    # can be represented as an integer, though many of those combinations
    # involve illegal transitions, duplicated letters, etc.
    # Iterate through all those possibilities and eliminate the illegal ones.
    my $maxIndex = $puzzleSize ** $maxPrefixLength;

    for (my $i = 0; $i < $maxIndex; $i++) {
        my @path;
        my $remainder = $i;
        my $prevPosition = -1;
        my $prefix = '';
        my %usedPositions = ();
        for (my $prefixLength = 1; $prefixLength <= $maxPrefixLength; $prefixLength++) {
            my $position = $remainder % $puzzleSize;

            # Is this a valid step?
            #  a. Is the transition legal (to an adjacent square)?
            if (! isLegalTransition($prevPosition, $position)) {
                last;
            }

            #  b. Have we repeated a square?
            if ($usedPositions{$position}) {
                last;
            }
            else {
                $usedPositions{$position} = 1;
            }

            # Record this prefix if length >= $minimumWordLength.
            $prefix .= $puzzle[$position];
            if ($prefixLength >= $minimumWordLength) {
                $prefixes{$prefix} = 1;
            }

            push @path, $position;
            $remainder -= $position;
            $remainder /= $puzzleSize;
            $prevPosition = $position;
        } # end inner for
    } # end outer for
    return %prefixes;
}

# Loop through all words in dictionary, looking for ones that are in the puzzle.
sub findWordsInPuzzle(@) {
    my @allWords = @_;
    my @wordsFound = ();
    my $puzzleSize = scalar @puzzle;
WORD: foreach my $word (@allWords) {
        my $wordLength = length($word);
        if ($wordLength > $puzzleSize || $wordLength < $minimumWordLength) {
            # Reject word as too short or too long.
        }
        elsif ($wordLength <= $maximumPrefixLength ) {
            # Word should be in the prefix hash.
            if ($prefixesInPuzzle{$word}) {
                push @wordsFound, $word;
            }
        }
        else {
            # Scan through the word using a window of length $maximumPrefixLength, looking for any strings not in our prefix list.
            # If any are found that are not in the list, this word is not possible.
            # If no non-matches are found, we have more work to do.
            my $limit = $wordLength - $maximumPrefixLength + 1;
            for (my $startIndex = 0; $startIndex < $limit; $startIndex ++) {
                if (! $prefixesInPuzzle{substr($word, $startIndex, $maximumPrefixLength)}) {
                    next WORD;
                }
            }
            if (isWordTraceable($word)) {
                # Additional test necessary: see if we can form this word by following legal transitions
                push @wordsFound, $word;
            }
        }

    }
    return @wordsFound;
}

# Is it possible to trace out the word using only legal transitions?
sub isWordTraceable($) {
    my $word = shift;
    return traverse([split(//, $word)], [-1]); # Start at special square -1, which may transition to any square in the puzzle.
}

# Recursively look for a path through the puzzle that matches the word.
sub traverse($$) {
    my ($lettersRef, $pathRef) = @_;
    my $index = scalar @$pathRef - 1;
    my $position = $pathRef->[$index];
    my $letter = $lettersRef->[$index];
    my $branchesRef =  $transitions{$position};
BRANCH: foreach my $branch (@$branchesRef) {
            if ($puzzle[$branch] eq $letter) {
                # Have we used this position yet?
                foreach my $usedBranch (@$pathRef) {
                    if ($usedBranch == $branch) {
                        next BRANCH;
                    }
                }
                if (scalar @$lettersRef == $index + 1) {
                    return 1; # End of word and success.
                }
                push @$pathRef, $branch;
                if (traverse($lettersRef, $pathRef)) {
                    return 1; # Recursive success.
                }
                else {
                    pop @$pathRef;
                }
            }
        }
    return 0; # No path found. Failed.
}
```

Comment: Has the location of dictionary changed? I tried to find the dictionary words since I wanted to compare my solution with everyone but I couldn't find it on the given link at /usr/share/dict . I know it's quite old thread but It be great if you can point me. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Don't have my Mac handy at the moment. All you need is a file with English words, one to a line, separated by newlines. You may find such a file on the internet. One is here: http://mieliestronk.com/corncob_lowercase.txt    but there are probably lists with more words than that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I had found that in ubuntu files.

Answer (score 9):

I know I'm super late but I made one of these a while ago in **PHP** - just for fun too...

http://www.lostsockdesign.com.au/sandbox/boggle/index.php?letters=fxieamloewbxastu
Found 75 words (133 pts) in **0.90108 seconds**

`F.........X..I..............E...............
A......................................M..............................L............................O...............................
E....................W............................B..........................X
A..................S..................................................T.................U....`

Gives some indication of what the program is actually doing - each letter is where it starts looking through the patterns while each '.' shows a path that it has tried to take. The more '.' there are the further it has searched.

Let me know if you want the code... it is a horrible mix of PHP and HTML that was never meant to see the light of day so I dare not post it here :P

Answer (score 9):

I spent 3 months working on a solution to the 10 best point dense 5x5 Boggle boards problem.

The problem is now solved and laid out with full disclosure on 5 web pages.  Please contact me with questions.

The board analysis algorithm uses an explicit stack to pseudo-recursively traverse the board squares through a Directed Acyclic Word Graph with direct child information, and a time stamp tracking mechanism.  This may very well be the world's most advanced lexicon data structure.

The scheme evaluates some 10,000 very good boards per second on a quad core. (9500+ points)

Parent Web Page:

DeepSearch.c - http://www.pathcom.com/~vadco/deep.html

Component Web Pages:

Optimal Scoreboard - http://www.pathcom.com/~vadco/binary.html

Advanced Lexicon Structure - http://www.pathcom.com/~vadco/adtdawg.html

Board Analysis Algorithm - http://www.pathcom.com/~vadco/guns.html

Parallel Batch Processing - http://www.pathcom.com/~vadco/parallel.html

-
This comprehensive body of work will only interest a person who demands the very best.

Comment: Your analysis is interesting, but your results are not technically Boggle boards. The 5x5 boggle game includes one die that contains the faces BJKQXZ, your implementation is explicitly excluding all of these letters and so the board position is not actually possible in a real Boggle game.

Answer (score 4):

First, read how one of the C# language designers solved a related problem: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/02/04/a-nasality-talisman-for-the-sultana-analyst.aspx.

Like him, you can start with a dictionary and the canonacalize words by creating a dictionary from an array of letters sorted alphabetically to a list of words that can be spelled from those letters.

Next, start creating the possible words from the board and looking them up. I suspect that will get you pretty far, but there are certainly more tricks that might speed things up.

Answer (score 4):

Does your search algorithm continually decrease the word list as your search continues?

For instance, in the search above there are only 13 letters that your words can start with (effectively reducing to half as many starting letters).

As you add more letter permutations it would further decrease the available word sets decreasing the searching necessary.

I'd start there.

Answer (score 4):

I'd have to give more thought to a complete solution, but as a handy optimisation, I wonder whether it might be worth pre-computing a table of frequencies of digrams and trigrams (2- and 3-letter combinations) based on all the words from your dictionary, and use this to prioritise your search. I'd go with the starting letters of words. So if your dictionary contained the words "India", "Water", "Extreme", and "Extraordinary", then your pre-computed table might be:

```
'IN': 1
'WA': 1
'EX': 2
```

Then search for these digrams in the order of commonality (first EX, then WA/IN)

Answer (score 4):

I suggest making a tree of letters based on words.  The tree would be composed of a letter structs, like this:

```
letter: char
isWord: boolean
```

Then you build up the tree, with each depth adding a new letter.  In other words, on the first level there'd be the alphabet; then from each of those trees, there'd be another another 26 entries, and so on, until you've spelled out all the words.  Hang onto this parsed tree, and it'll make all possible answers faster to look up.

With this parsed tree, you can very quickly find solutions.  Here's the pseudo-code:

```
BEGIN: 
    For each letter:
        if the struct representing it on the current depth has isWord == true, enter it as an answer.
        Cycle through all its neighbors; if there is a child of the current node corresponding to the letter, recursively call BEGIN on it.
```

This could be sped up with a bit of dynamic programming.  For example, in your sample, the two 'A's are both next to an 'E' and a 'W', which (from the point they hit them on) would be identical.  I don't have enough time to really spell out the code for this, but I think you can gather the idea.

Also, I'm sure you'll find other solutions if you Google for "Boggle solver".

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun, I implemented one in bash. 
It is not super fast, but reasonable.

http://dev.xkyle.com/bashboggle/

Answer (score 3):

Hilarious. I nearly posted the same question a few days ago due to the same damn game! I did not however because just searched google for [boggle solver python](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en-us&q=boggle+solver+python&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) and got all the answers I could want.

Comment: I wasn't aware the popular name of it was "boggle", but I did find some stuff on google, I was just curious to see what people would come up with on SO. :)

Answer (score 3):

I realize this question's time has come and gone, but since I was working on a solver myself, and stumbled onto this while googling about, I thought I should post a reference to mine as it seems a bit different from some of the others.

I chose to go with a flat array for the game board, and to do recursive hunts from each letter on the board, traversing from valid neighbor to valid neighbor, extending the hunt if the current list of letters if a valid prefix in an index. While traversing the notion of the current word is list of indexes into board, not letters that make up a word. When checking the index, the indexes are translated to letters and the check done.

The index is a brute force dictionary that's a bit like a trie, but allows for Pythonic queries of the index. If the words 'cat' and 'cater' are in the list, you'll get this in the dictionary:

```
   d = { 'c': ['cat','cater'],
     'ca': ['cat','cater'],
     'cat': ['cat','cater'],
     'cate': ['cater'],
     'cater': ['cater'],
   }
```

So if the current_word is 'ca' you know that it is a valid prefix because `'ca' in d` returns True (so continue the board traversal). And if the current_word is 'cat' then you know that it is a valid word because it is a valid prefix and `'cat' in d['cat']` returns True too.

If felt like this allowed for some readable code that doesn't seem too slow. Like everyone else the expense in this system is reading/building the index. Solving the board is pretty much noise.

The code is at http://gist.github.com/268079. It is intentionally vertical and naive with lots of explicit validity checking because I wanted to understand the problem without crufting it up with a bunch of magic or obscurity.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote my solver in C++. I implemented a custom tree structure. I'm not sure it can be considered a trie but it's similar. Each node has 26 branches, 1 for each letter of the alphabet. I traverse the branches of the boggle board in parallel with the branches of my dictionary. If the branch does not exist in the dictionary, I stop searching it on the Boggle board. I convert all the letters on the board to ints. So 'A' = 0. Since it's just arrays, lookup is always O(1). Each node stores if it completes a word and how many words exist in its children. The tree is pruned as words are found to reduce repeatedly searching for the same words. I believe pruning is also O(1).

CPU: Pentium SU2700 1.3GHz
RAM: 3gb

Loads dictionary of 178,590 words in < 1 second.
Solves 100x100 Boggle (boggle.txt) in 4 seconds. ~44,000 words found.
Solving a 4x4 Boggle is too fast to provide a meaningful benchmark. :)

[Fast Boggle Solver GitHub Repo](https://github.com/themachineswillwin/fast-boggle-solver)

Answer (score 2):

Given a Boggle board with N rows and M columns, let's assume the following:

- N*M is substantially greater than the number of possible words
- N*M is substantially greater than the longest possible word

Under these assumptions, the complexity of this solution is O(N*M).

I think comparing running times for this one example board in many ways misses the point but, for the sake of completeness, this solution completes in <0.2s on my modern MacBook Pro.

This solution will find all possible paths for each word in the corpus.

```ruby
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# Example usage: ./boggle-solver --board "fxie amlo ewbx astu"

autoload :Matrix, 'matrix'
autoload :OptionParser, 'optparse'

DEFAULT_CORPUS_PATH = '/usr/share/dict/words'.freeze

# Functions

def filter_corpus(matrix, corpus, min_word_length)
  board_char_counts = Hash.new(0)
  matrix.each { |c| board_char_counts[c] += 1 }

  max_word_length = matrix.row_count * matrix.column_count
  boggleable_regex = /^[#{board_char_counts.keys.reduce(:+)}]{#{min_word_length},#{max_word_length}}$/
  corpus.select{ |w| w.match boggleable_regex }.select do |w|
    word_char_counts = Hash.new(0)
    w.each_char { |c| word_char_counts[c] += 1 }
    word_char_counts.all? { |c, count| board_char_counts[c] >= count }
  end
end

def neighbors(point, matrix)
  i, j = point
  ([i-1, 0].max .. [i+1, matrix.row_count-1].min).inject([]) do |r, new_i|
    ([j-1, 0].max .. [j+1, matrix.column_count-1].min).inject(r) do |r, new_j|
      neighbor = [new_i, new_j]
      neighbor.eql?(point) ? r : r << neighbor
    end
  end
end

def expand_path(path, word, matrix)
  return [path] if path.length == word.length

  next_char = word[path.length]
  viable_neighbors = neighbors(path[-1], matrix).select do |point|
    !path.include?(point) && matrix.element(*point).eql?(next_char)
  end

  viable_neighbors.inject([]) do |result, point|
    result + expand_path(path.dup << point, word, matrix)
  end
end

def find_paths(word, matrix)
  result = []
  matrix.each_with_index do |c, i, j|
    result += expand_path([[i, j]], word, matrix) if c.eql?(word[0])
  end
  result
end

def solve(matrix, corpus, min_word_length: 3)
  boggleable_corpus = filter_corpus(matrix, corpus, min_word_length)
  boggleable_corpus.inject({}) do |result, w|
    paths = find_paths(w, matrix)
    result[w] = paths unless paths.empty?
    result
  end
end

# Script

options = { corpus_path: DEFAULT_CORPUS_PATH }
option_parser = OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.banner = 'Usage: boggle-solver --board <value> [--corpus <value>]'

  opts.on('--board BOARD', String, 'The board (e.g. "fxi aml ewb ast")') do |b|
    options[:board] = b
  end

  opts.on('--corpus CORPUS_PATH', String, 'Corpus file path') do |c|
    options[:corpus_path] = c
  end

  opts.on_tail('-h', '--help', 'Shows usage') do
    STDOUT.puts opts
    exit
  end
end
option_parser.parse!

unless options[:board]
  STDERR.puts option_parser
  exit false
end

unless File.file? options[:corpus_path]
  STDERR.puts "No corpus exists - #{options[:corpus_path]}"
  exit false
end

rows = options[:board].downcase.scan(/\S+/).map{ |row| row.scan(/./) }

raw_corpus = File.readlines(options[:corpus_path])
corpus = raw_corpus.map{ |w| w.downcase.rstrip }.uniq.sort

solution = solve(Matrix.rows(rows), corpus)
solution.each_pair do |w, paths|
  STDOUT.puts w
  paths.each do |path|
    STDOUT.puts "\t" + path.map{ |point| point.inspect }.join(', ')
  end
end
STDOUT.puts "TOTAL: #{solution.count}"
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution also gives the direction to search in the given board

Algo:

```
1. Uses trie to save all the word in the english to fasten the search
2. The uses DFS to search the words in Boggle
```

Output:

```
Found "pic" directions from (4,0)(p) go  → →
Found "pick" directions from (4,0)(p) go  → → ↑
Found "pickman" directions from (4,0)(p) go  → → ↑ ↑ ↖ ↑
Found "picket" directions from (4,0)(p) go  → → ↑ ↗ ↖
Found "picked" directions from (4,0)(p) go  → → ↑ ↗ ↘
Found "pickle" directions from (4,0)(p) go  → → ↑ ↘ →
```

Code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from nltk.corpus import words
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

english_words = words.words()

# If you wan to remove stop words
# stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
# english_words = [w for w in english_words if w not in stop_words]

boggle = [
    ['c', 'n', 't', 's', 's'],
    ['d', 'a', 't', 'i', 'n'],
    ['o', 'o', 'm', 'e', 'l'],
    ['s', 'i', 'k', 'n', 'd'],
    ['p', 'i', 'c', 'l', 'e']
]

# Instead of X and Y co-ordinates
# better to use Row and column
lenc = len(boggle[0])
lenr = len(boggle)

# Initialize trie datastructure
trie_node = {'valid': False, 'next': {}}

# lets get the delta to find all the nighbors
neighbors_delta = [
    (-1,-1, "↖"),
    (-1, 0, "↑"),
    (-1, 1, "↗"),
    (0, -1, "←"),
    (0,  1, "→"),
    (1, -1, "↙"),
    (1,  0, "↓"),
    (1,  1, "↘"),
]


def gen_trie(word, node):
    """udpates the trie datastructure using the given word"""
    if not word:
        return

    if word[0] not in node:
        node[word[0]] = {'valid': len(word) == 1, 'next': {}}

    # recursively build trie
    gen_trie(word[1:], node[word[0]])


def build_trie(words, trie):
    """Builds trie data structure from the list of words given"""
    for word in words:
        gen_trie(word, trie)
    return trie


def get_neighbors(r, c):
    """Returns the neighbors for a given co-ordinates"""
    n = []
    for neigh in neighbors_delta:
        new_r = r + neigh[0]
        new_c = c + neigh[1]

        if (new_r >= lenr) or (new_c >= lenc) or (new_r < 0) or (new_c < 0):
            continue
        n.append((new_r, new_c, neigh[2]))
    return n


def dfs(r, c, visited, trie, now_word, direction):
    """Scan the graph using DFS"""
    if (r, c) in visited:
        return

    letter = boggle[r][c]
    visited.append((r, c))

    if letter in trie:
        now_word += letter

        if trie[letter]['valid']:
            print('Found "{}" {}'.format(now_word, direction))

        neighbors = get_neighbors(r, c)
        for n in neighbors:
            dfs(n[0], n[1], visited[::], trie[letter], now_word, direction + " " + n[2])


def main(trie_node):
    """Initiate the search for words in boggle"""
    trie_node = build_trie(english_words, trie_node)

    # print the board
    print("Given board")
    for i in range(lenr):print (boggle[i])
    print ('\n')

    for r in range(lenr):
        for c in range(lenc):
            letter = boggle[r][c]
            dfs(r, c, [], trie_node, '', 'directions from ({},{})({}) go '.format(r, c, letter))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(trie_node)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have [implemented a solution in OCaml](https://github.com/VictorNicollet/Boggle). It pre-compiles a dictionary as a trie, and uses two-letter sequence frequencies to eliminate edges that could never appear in a word to further speed up processing.

It solves your example board in 0.35ms (with an additional 6ms start-up time which is mostly related to loading the trie into memory).

The solutions found:

```
["swami"; "emile"; "limbs"; "limbo"; "limes"; "amble"; "tubs"; "stub";
 "swam"; "semi"; "seam"; "awes"; "buts"; "bole"; "boil"; "west"; "east";
 "emil"; "lobs"; "limb"; "lime"; "lima"; "mesa"; "mews"; "mewl"; "maws";
 "milo"; "mile"; "awes"; "amie"; "axle"; "elma"; "fame"; "ubs"; "tux"; "tub";
 "twa"; "twa"; "stu"; "saw"; "sea"; "sew"; "sea"; "awe"; "awl"; "but"; "btu";
 "box"; "bmw"; "was"; "wax"; "oil"; "lox"; "lob"; "leo"; "lei"; "lie"; "mes";
 "mew"; "mae"; "maw"; "max"; "mil"; "mix"; "awe"; "awl"; "elm"; "eli"; "fax"]
```

Comment: This is nice, but all the times posted here involve any "start-up" time to load the dictionary into memory, so comparing the 0.35 to the other times is pretty far from accurate. Also, are you using a different dictionary? You're missing some words. Either way, +1

Comment: The start-up time takes 6ms, so you're looking at 6.35ms for a complete run. I am using my local `/usr/share/dict` dictionary, and some of the words are indeed missing (such as EMBOLE).

Answer (score 1):

A Node.JS JavaScript solution. Computes all 100 unique words in less than a second which includes reading dictionary file (MBA 2012).

Output:
["FAM","TUX","TUB","FAE","ELI","ELM","ELB","TWA","TWA","SAW","AMI","SWA","SWA","AME","SEA","SEW","AES","AWL","AWE","SEA","AWA","MIX","MIL","AST","ASE","MAX","MAE","MAW","MEW","AWE","MES","AWL","LIE","LIM","AWA","AES","BUT","BLO","WAS","WAE","WEA","LEI","LEO","LOB","LOX","WEM","OIL","OLM","WEA","WAE","WAX","WAF","MILO","EAST","WAME","TWAS","TWAE","EMIL","WEAM","OIME","AXIL","WEST","TWAE","LIMB","WASE","WAST","BLEO","STUB","BOIL","BOLE","LIME","SAWT","LIMA","MESA","MEWL","AXLE","FAME","ASEM","MILE","AMIL","SEAX","SEAM","SEMI","SWAM","AMBO","AMLI","AXILE","AMBLE","SWAMI","AWEST","AWEST","LIMAX","LIMES","LIMBU","LIMBO","EMBOX","SEMBLE","EMBOLE","WAMBLE","FAMBLE"]

Code:

```
var fs = require('fs')

var Node = function(value, row, col) {
    this.value = value
    this.row = row
    this.col = col
}

var Path = function() {
    this.nodes = []
}

Path.prototype.push = function(node) {
    this.nodes.push(node)
    return this
}

Path.prototype.contains = function(node) {
    for (var i = 0, ii = this.nodes.length; i < ii; i++) {
        if (this.nodes[i] === node) {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}

Path.prototype.clone = function() {
    var path = new Path()
    path.nodes = this.nodes.slice(0)
    return path
}

Path.prototype.to_word = function() {
    var word = ''

    for (var i = 0, ii = this.nodes.length; i < ii; ++i) {
        word += this.nodes[i].value
    }

    return word
}

var Board = function(nodes, dict) {
    // Expects n x m array.
    this.nodes = nodes
    this.words = []
    this.row_count = nodes.length
    this.col_count = nodes[0].length
    this.dict = dict
}

Board.from_raw = function(board, dict) {
    var ROW_COUNT = board.length
      , COL_COUNT = board[0].length

    var nodes = []

    // Replace board with Nodes
    for (var i = 0, ii = ROW_COUNT; i < ii; ++i) {
        nodes.push([])
        for (var j = 0, jj = COL_COUNT; j < jj; ++j) {
            nodes[i].push(new Node(board[i][j], i, j))
        }
    }

    return new Board(nodes, dict)
}

Board.prototype.toString = function() {
    return JSON.stringify(this.nodes)
}

Board.prototype.update_potential_words = function(dict) {
    for (var i = 0, ii = this.row_count; i < ii; ++i) {
        for (var j = 0, jj = this.col_count; j < jj; ++j) {
            var node = this.nodes[i][j]
              , path = new Path()

            path.push(node)

            this.dfs_search(path)
        }
    }
}

Board.prototype.on_board = function(row, col) {
    return 0 <= row && row < this.row_count && 0 <= col && col < this.col_count
}

Board.prototype.get_unsearched_neighbours = function(path) {
    var last_node = path.nodes[path.nodes.length - 1]

    var offsets = [
        [-1, -1], [-1,  0], [-1, +1]
      , [ 0, -1],           [ 0, +1]
      , [+1, -1], [+1,  0], [+1, +1]
    ]

    var neighbours = []

    for (var i = 0, ii = offsets.length; i < ii; ++i) {
        var offset = offsets[i]
        if (this.on_board(last_node.row + offset[0], last_node.col + offset[1])) {

            var potential_node = this.nodes[last_node.row + offset[0]][last_node.col + offset[1]]
            if (!path.contains(potential_node)) {
                // Create a new path if on board and we haven't visited this node yet.
                neighbours.push(potential_node)
            }
        }
    }

    return neighbours
}

Board.prototype.dfs_search = function(path) {
    var path_word = path.to_word()

    if (this.dict.contains_exact(path_word) && path_word.length >= 3) {
        this.words.push(path_word)
    }

    var neighbours = this.get_unsearched_neighbours(path)

    for (var i = 0, ii = neighbours.length; i < ii; ++i) {
        var neighbour = neighbours[i]
        var new_path = path.clone()
        new_path.push(neighbour)

        if (this.dict.contains_prefix(new_path.to_word())) {
            this.dfs_search(new_path)
        }
    }
}

var Dict = function() {
    this.dict_array = []

    var dict_data = fs.readFileSync('./web2', 'utf8')
    var dict_array = dict_data.split('\n')

    for (var i = 0, ii = dict_array.length; i < ii; ++i) {
        dict_array[i] = dict_array[i].toUpperCase()
    }

    this.dict_array = dict_array.sort()
}

Dict.prototype.contains_prefix = function(prefix) {
    // Binary search
    return this.search_prefix(prefix, 0, this.dict_array.length)
}

Dict.prototype.contains_exact = function(exact) {
    // Binary search
    return this.search_exact(exact, 0, this.dict_array.length)
}

Dict.prototype.search_prefix = function(prefix, start, end) {
    if (start >= end) {
        // If no more place to search, return no matter what.
        return this.dict_array[start].indexOf(prefix) > -1
    }

    var middle = Math.floor((start + end)/2)

    if (this.dict_array[middle].indexOf(prefix) > -1) {
        // If we prefix exists, return true.
        return true
    } else {
        // Recurse
        if (prefix <= this.dict_array[middle]) {
            return this.search_prefix(prefix, start, middle - 1)
        } else {
            return this.search_prefix(prefix, middle + 1, end)
        }
    }
}

Dict.prototype.search_exact = function(exact, start, end) {
    if (start >= end) {
        // If no more place to search, return no matter what.
        return this.dict_array[start] === exact
    }

    var middle = Math.floor((start + end)/2)

    if (this.dict_array[middle] === exact) {
        // If we prefix exists, return true.
        return true
    } else {
        // Recurse
        if (exact <= this.dict_array[middle]) {
            return this.search_exact(exact, start, middle - 1)
        } else {
            return this.search_exact(exact, middle + 1, end)
        }
    }
}

var board = [
    ['F', 'X', 'I', 'E']
  , ['A', 'M', 'L', 'O']
  , ['E', 'W', 'B', 'X']
  , ['A', 'S', 'T', 'U']
]

var dict = new Dict()

var b = Board.from_raw(board, dict)
b.update_potential_words()
console.log(JSON.stringify(b.words.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.length - b.length
})))
```

Answer (score 1):

So I wanted to add another PHP way of solving this, since everyone loves PHP.
There's a little bit of refactoring I would like to do, like using a regexpression match against the dictionary file, but right now I'm just loading the entire dictionary file into a wordList.

I did this using a linked list idea. Each Node has a character value, a location value, and a next pointer.

The location value is how I found out if two nodes are connected.

```
1     2     3     4
11    12    13    14
21    22    23    24
31    32    33    34
```

So using that grid, I know two nodes are connected if the first node's location equals the second nodes location +/- 1 for the same row, +/- 9, 10, 11 for the row above and below.

I use recursion for the main search. It takes a word off the wordList, finds all the possible starting points, and then recursively finds the next possible connection, keeping in mind that it can't go to a location it's already using (which is why I add $notInLoc).

Anyway, I know it needs some refactoring, and would love to hear thoughts on how to make it cleaner, but it produces the correct results based on the dictionary file I'm using. Depending on the number of vowels and combinations on the board, it takes about 3 to 6 seconds. I know that once I preg_match the dictionary results, that will reduce significantly.

```
<?php
    ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_depth', 20);
    ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_children', 1024);
    ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_data', 1024);

    class Node {
        var $loc;

        function __construct($value) {
            $this->value = $value;
            $next = null;
        }
    }

    class Boggle {
        var $root;
        var $locList = array (1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 12, 13, 14, 21, 22, 23, 24, 31, 32, 33, 34);
        var $wordList = [];
        var $foundWords = [];

        function __construct($board) {
            // Takes in a board string and creates all the nodes
            $node = new Node($board[0]);
            $node->loc = $this->locList[0];
            $this->root = $node;
            for ($i = 1; $i < strlen($board); $i++) {
                    $node->next = new Node($board[$i]);
                    $node->next->loc = $this->locList[$i];
                    $node = $node->next;
            }
            // Load in a dictionary file
            // Use regexp to elimate all the words that could never appear and load the 
            // rest of the words into wordList
            $handle = fopen("dict.txt", "r");
            if ($handle) {
                while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
                    // process the line read.
                    $line = trim($line);
                    if (strlen($line) > 2) {
                        $this->wordList[] = trim($line);
                    }
                }
                fclose($handle);
            } else {
                // error opening the file.
                echo "Problem with the file.";
            } 
        }

        function isConnected($node1, $node2) {
        // Determines if 2 nodes are connected on the boggle board

            return (($node1->loc == $node2->loc + 1) || ($node1->loc == $node2->loc - 1) ||
               ($node1->loc == $node2->loc - 9) || ($node1->loc == $node2->loc - 10) || ($node1->loc == $node2->loc - 11) ||
               ($node1->loc == $node2->loc + 9) || ($node1->loc == $node2->loc + 10) || ($node1->loc == $node2->loc + 11)) ? true : false;

        }

        function find($value, $notInLoc = []) {
            // Returns a node with the value that isn't in a location
            $current = $this->root;
            while($current) {
                if ($current->value == $value && !in_array($current->loc, $notInLoc)) {
                    return $current;
                }
                if (isset($current->next)) {
                    $current = $current->next;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        function findAll($value) {
            // Returns an array of nodes with a specific value
            $current = $this->root;
            $foundNodes = [];
            while ($current) {
                if ($current->value == $value) {
                    $foundNodes[] = $current;
                }
                if (isset($current->next)) {
                    $current = $current->next;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return (empty($foundNodes)) ? false : $foundNodes;
        }

        function findAllConnectedTo($node, $value, $notInLoc = []) {
            // Returns an array of nodes that are connected to a specific node and 
            // contain a specific value and are not in a certain location
            $nodeList = $this->findAll($value);
            $newList = [];
            if ($nodeList) {
                foreach ($nodeList as $node2) {
                    if (!in_array($node2->loc, $notInLoc) && $this->isConnected($node, $node2)) {
                        $newList[] = $node2;
                    }
                }
            }
            return (empty($newList)) ? false : $newList;
        }



        function inner($word, $list, $i = 0, $notInLoc = []) {
            $i++;
            foreach($list as $node) {
                $notInLoc[] = $node->loc;
                if ($list2 = $this->findAllConnectedTo($node, $word[$i], $notInLoc)) {
                    if ($i == (strlen($word) - 1)) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return $this->inner($word, $list2, $i, $notInLoc);
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        function findWord($word) {
            if ($list = $this->findAll($word[0])) {
                return $this->inner($word, $list);
            }
            return false;
        }

        function findAllWords() {
            foreach($this->wordList as $word) {
                if ($this->findWord($word)) {
                    $this->foundWords[] = $word;
                }
            }
        }

        function displayBoard() {
            $current = $this->root;
            for ($i=0; $i < 4; $i++) {
                echo $current->value . " " . $current->next->value . " " . $current->next->next->value . " " . $current->next->next->next->value . "<br />";
                if ($i < 3) {
                    $current = $current->next->next->next->next;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    function randomBoardString() {
        return substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 16)), 0, 16);
    }

    $myBoggle = new Boggle(randomBoardString());
    $myBoggle->displayBoard();
    $x = microtime(true);
    $myBoggle->findAllWords();
    $y = microtime(true);
    echo ($y-$x);
    var_dump($myBoggle->foundWords);

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know I am really late at the party but I have implemented, as a coding exercise, a boggle solver in several programming languages (C++, Java, Go, C#, Python, Ruby, JavaScript, Julia, Lua, PHP, Perl) and I thought that someone might be interested in those, so I leave link here:
https://github.com/AmokHuginnsson/boggle-solvers

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution Using Predefined words in NLTK toolkit 
NLTK has nltk.corpus package in that we have package called words and it contains more than 2Lakhs English words you can simply use all into your program.

Once creating your matrix convert it into a character array and perform this code

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import words
from collections import Counter

def possibleWords(input, charSet):
    for word in input:
        dict = Counter(word)
        flag = 1
        for key in dict.keys():
            if key not in charSet:
                flag = 0
        if flag == 1 and len(word)>5: #its depends if you want only length more than 5 use this otherwise remove that one. 
            print(word)


nltk.download('words')
word_list = words.words()
# prints 236736
print(len(word_list))
charSet = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'o', 'n', 'v', 't']
possibleWords(word_list, charSet)
```

Output:

```
eleven
eleventh
elevon
entente
entone
ethene
ethenol
evolve
evolvent
hellhole
helvell
hooven
letten
looten
nettle
nonene
nonent
nonlevel
notelet
novelet
novelette
novene
teenet
teethe
teevee
telethon
tellee
tenent
tentlet
theelol
toetoe
tonlet
toothlet
tootle
tottle
vellon
velvet
velveteen
venene
vennel
venthole
voeten
volent
volvelle
volvent
voteen
```

I hope you get it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my java implementation: https://github.com/zouzhile/interview/blob/master/src/com/interview/algorithms/tree/BoggleSolver.java

Trie build took 0 hours, 0 minutes, 1 seconds, 532 milliseconds
Word searching took 0 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds, 92 milliseconds

```
eel eeler eely eer eke eker eld eleut elk ell 
elle epee epihippus ere erept err error erupt eurus eye 
eyer eyey hip hipe hiper hippish hipple hippus his hish 
hiss hist hler hsi ihi iphis isis issue issuer ist 
isurus kee keek keeker keel keeler keep keeper keld kele 
kelek kelep kelk kell kelly kelp kelper kep kepi kept 
ker kerel kern keup keuper key kyl kyle lee leek 
leeky leep leer lek leo leper leptus lepus ler leu 
ley lleu lue lull luller lulu lunn lunt lunule luo 
lupe lupis lupulus lupus lur lure lurer lush lushly lust 
lustrous lut lye nul null nun nupe nurture nurturer nut 
oer ore ort ouphish our oust out outpeep outpeer outpipe 
outpull outpush output outre outrun outrush outspell outspue outspurn outspurt 
outstrut outstunt outsulk outturn outusure oyer pee peek peel peele 
peeler peeoy peep peeper peepeye peer pele peleus pell peller 
pelu pep peplus pepper pepperer pepsis per pern pert pertussis 
peru perule perun peul phi pip pipe piper pipi pipistrel 
pipistrelle pipistrellus pipper pish piss pist plup plus plush ply 
plyer psi pst puerer pul pule puler pulk pull puller 
pulley pullus pulp pulper pulu puly pun punt pup puppis 
pur pure puree purely purer purr purre purree purrel purrer 
puru purupuru pus push puss pustule put putt puture ree 
reek reeker reeky reel reeler reeper rel rely reoutput rep 
repel repeller repipe reply repp reps reree rereel rerun reuel 
roe roer roey roue rouelle roun roup rouper roust rout 
roy rue ruelle ruer rule ruler rull ruller run runt 
rupee rupert rupture ruru rus rush russ rust rustre rut 
shi shih ship shipper shish shlu sip sipe siper sipper 
sis sish sisi siss sissu sist sistrurus speel speer spelk 
spell speller splurt spun spur spurn spurrer spurt sput ssi 
ssu stre stree streek streel streeler streep streke streperous strepsis 
strey stroup stroy stroyer strue strunt strut stu stue stull 
stuller stun stunt stupe stupeous stupp sturnus sturt stuss stut 
sue suer suerre suld sulk sulker sulky sull sully sulu 
sun sunn sunt sunup sup supe super superoutput supper supple 
supplely supply sur sure surely surrey sus susi susu susurr 
susurrous susurrus sutu suture suu tree treey trek trekker trey 
troupe trouper trout troy true truer trull truller truly trun 
trush truss trust tshi tst tsun tsutsutsi tue tule tulle 
tulu tun tunu tup tupek tupi tur turn turnup turr 
turus tush tussis tussur tut tuts tutu tutulus ule ull 
uller ulu ululu unreel unrule unruly unrun unrust untrue untruly 
untruss untrust unturn unurn upper upperer uppish uppishly uppull uppush 
upspurt upsun upsup uptree uptruss upturn ure urn uro uru 
urus urushi ush ust usun usure usurer utu yee yeel 
yeld yelk yell yeller yelp yelper yeo yep yer yere 
yern yoe yor yore you youl youp your yourn yoy
```

**Note:**
I used the dictionary and character matrix at the beginning of this thread. The code was run on my MacBookPro, below is some information about the machine.

Model Name:   MacBook Pro
  Model Identifier: MacBookPro8,1
  Processor Name:   Intel Core i5
  Processor Speed:  2.3 GHz
  Number Of Processors: 1
  Total Number Of Cores:    2
  L2 Cache (per core):  256 KB
  L3 Cache: 3 MB
  Memory:   4 GB
  Boot ROM Version: MBP81.0047.B0E
  SMC Version (system): 1.68f96

Answer (score 0):

I solved this too, with Java. My implementation is 269 lines long and pretty easy to use. First you need to create a new instance of the Boggler class and then call the solve function with the grid as a parameter. It takes about 100 ms to load the dictionary of 50 000 words on my computer and it finds the words in about 10-20 ms. The found words are stored in an ArrayList, `foundWords`.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Boggler {
    private ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();      
    private ArrayList<String> roundWords = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    private ArrayList<Word> foundWords = new ArrayList<Word>();     
    private char[][] letterGrid = new char[4][4];                   
    private String letters;                                         

    public Boggler() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, URISyntaxException {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        URL path = GUI.class.getResource("words.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File(path.toURI()).getAbsolutePath()), "iso-8859-1"));
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line.length() < 3 || line.length() > 10) {
                continue;
            }

            this.words.add(line);
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Word> getWords() {
        return this.foundWords;
    }

    public void solve(String letters) {
        this.letters = "";
        this.foundWords = new ArrayList<Word>();

        for(int i = 0; i < letters.length(); i++) {
            if(!this.letters.contains(letters.substring(i, i + 1))) {
                this.letters += letters.substring(i, i + 1);
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                this.letterGrid[i][j] = letters.charAt(i * 4 + j);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(this.letterGrid));               

        this.roundWords = new ArrayList<String>();      
        String pattern = "[" + this.letters + "]+";     

        for(int i = 0; i < this.words.size(); i++) {

            if(this.words.get(i).matches(pattern)) {
                this.roundWords.add(this.words.get(i));
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < this.roundWords.size(); i++) {
            Word word = checkForWord(this.roundWords.get(i));

            if(word != null) {
                System.out.println(word);
                this.foundWords.add(word);
            }
        }       
    }

    private Word checkForWord(String word) {
        char initial = word.charAt(0);
        ArrayList<LetterCoord> startPoints = new ArrayList<LetterCoord>();

        int x = 0;  
        int y = 0;
        for(char[] row: this.letterGrid) {
            x = 0;

            for(char letter: row) {
                if(initial == letter) {
                    startPoints.add(new LetterCoord(x, y));
                }

                x++;
            }

            y++;
        }

        ArrayList<LetterCoord> letterCoords = null;
        for(int initialTry = 0; initialTry < startPoints.size(); initialTry++) {
            letterCoords = new ArrayList<LetterCoord>();    

            x = startPoints.get(initialTry).getX(); 
            y = startPoints.get(initialTry).getY();

            LetterCoord initialCoord = new LetterCoord(x, y);
            letterCoords.add(initialCoord);

            letterLoop: for(int letterIndex = 1; letterIndex < word.length(); letterIndex++) {
                LetterCoord lastCoord = letterCoords.get(letterCoords.size() - 1);  
                char currentChar = word.charAt(letterIndex);                        

                ArrayList<LetterCoord> letterLocations = getNeighbours(currentChar, lastCoord.getX(), lastCoord.getY());

                if(letterLocations == null) {
                    return null;    
                }       

                for(int foundIndex = 0; foundIndex < letterLocations.size(); foundIndex++) {
                    if(letterIndex != word.length() - 1 && true == false) {
                        char nextChar = word.charAt(letterIndex + 1);
                        int lastX = letterCoords.get(letterCoords.size() - 1).getX();
                        int lastY = letterCoords.get(letterCoords.size() - 1).getY();

                        ArrayList<LetterCoord> possibleIndex = getNeighbours(nextChar, lastX, lastY);
                        if(possibleIndex != null) {
                            if(!letterCoords.contains(letterLocations.get(foundIndex))) {
                                letterCoords.add(letterLocations.get(foundIndex));
                            }
                            continue letterLoop;
                        } else {
                            return null;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if(!letterCoords.contains(letterLocations.get(foundIndex))) {
                            letterCoords.add(letterLocations.get(foundIndex));

                            continue letterLoop;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if(letterCoords != null) {
                if(letterCoords.size() == word.length()) {
                    Word w = new Word(word);
                    w.addList(letterCoords);
                    return w;
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }

        if(letterCoords != null) {
            Word foundWord = new Word(word);
            foundWord.addList(letterCoords);

            return foundWord;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public ArrayList<LetterCoord> getNeighbours(char letterToSearch, int x, int y) {
        ArrayList<LetterCoord> neighbours = new ArrayList<LetterCoord>();

        for(int _y = y - 1; _y <= y + 1; _y++) {
            for(int _x = x - 1; _x <= x + 1; _x++) {
                if(_x < 0 || _y < 0 || (_x == x && _y == y) || _y > 3 || _x > 3) {
                    continue;
                }

                if(this.letterGrid[_y][_x] == letterToSearch && !neighbours.contains(new LetterCoord(_x, _y))) {
                    neighbours.add(new LetterCoord(_x, _y));
                }
            }
        }

        if(neighbours.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return neighbours;
        }
    }
}

class Word {
    private String word;    
    private ArrayList<LetterCoord> letterCoords = new ArrayList<LetterCoord>();

    public Word(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

    public boolean addCoords(int x, int y) {
        LetterCoord lc = new LetterCoord(x, y);

        if(!this.letterCoords.contains(lc)) {
            this.letterCoords.add(lc);

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void addList(ArrayList<LetterCoord> letterCoords) {
        this.letterCoords = letterCoords;
    } 

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String outputString = this.word + " ";
        for(int i = 0; i < letterCoords.size(); i++) {
            outputString += "(" + letterCoords.get(i).getX() + ", " + letterCoords.get(i).getY() + ") ";
        }

        return outputString;
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return this.word;
    }

    public ArrayList<LetterCoord> getList() {
        return this.letterCoords;
    }
}

class LetterCoord extends ArrayList {
    private int x;          
    private int y;          

    public LetterCoord(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return this.x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return this.y;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if(!(o instanceof LetterCoord)) {
            return false;
        }

        LetterCoord lc = (LetterCoord) o;

        if(this.x == lc.getX() &&
                this.y == lc.getY()) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 29 * hash + this.x;
        hash = 24 * hash + this.y;
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in c. It takes around 48 ms to run on my machine (with around 98% of the time spent loading the dictionary from disk and creating the trie). The dictionary is /usr/share/dict/american-english which has 62886 words.

[Source code](https://github.com/ealter/Boggle-Solver)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this perfectly and very fast. I put it into an android app. View the video at the play store link to see it in action.

Word Cheats is an app that "cracks" any matrix style word game. This app was built
to to help me cheat at word scrambler. It can be used for word searches,
ruzzle, words, word finder, word crack, boggle, and more!

It can be seen here
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.harris.wordcracker

View the app in action in the video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DL2974WmNAI

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this in C#, using a DFA algorithm. You can check out my code at

https://github.com/attilabicsko/wordshuffler/

In addition to finding words in a matrix, my algorithm saves the actual paths for the words, so for designing a word finder game, you can check wether there is a word on an actual path.

Answer (score 0):

How about simple sorting and using the **binary search** in the dictionary?

Returns whole list in **0.35 sec** and can be further optimized (by for instance removing words with unused letters etc.).

```
from bisect import bisect_left

f = open("dict.txt")
D.extend([line.strip() for line in f.readlines()])
D = sorted(D)

def neibs(M,x,y):
    n = len(M)
    for i in xrange(-1,2):
        for j in xrange(-1,2):
            if (i == 0 and j == 0) or (x + i < 0 or x + i >= n or y + j < 0 or y + j >= n):
                continue
            yield (x + i, y + j)

def findWords(M,D,x,y,prefix):
    prefix = prefix + M[x][y]

    # find word in dict by binary search
    found = bisect_left(D,prefix)

    # if found then yield
    if D[found] == prefix: 
        yield prefix

    # if what we found is not even a prefix then return
    # (there is no point in going further)
    if len(D[found]) < len(prefix) or D[found][:len(prefix)] != prefix:
        return

    # recourse
    for neib in neibs(M,x,y):
        for word in findWords(M,D,neib[0], neib[1], prefix):
            yield word

def solve(M,D):
    # check each starting point
    for x in xrange(0,len(M)):
        for y in xrange(0,len(M)):
            for word in findWords(M,D,x,y,""):
                yield word

grid = "fxie amlo ewbx astu".split()
print [x for x in solve(grid,D)]
```

Comment: I tried this but. first you have to say D is a list. ... otherwise you gen an error. then I get     "if D[found] == prefix: IndexError: list index out of range". I might be doing something wrong. Python 2.7+

Answer (score 0):

```
    package ProblemSolving;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Given a 2-dimensional array of characters and a
 * dictionary in which a word can be searched in O(1) time.
 * Need to print all the words from array which are present
 * in dictionary. Word can be formed in any direction but
 * has to end at any edge of array.
 * (Need not worry much about the dictionary)
 */
public class DictionaryWord {
    private static char[][] matrix = new char[][]{
            {'a', 'f', 'h', 'u', 'n'},
            {'e', 't', 'a', 'i', 'r'},
            {'a', 'e', 'g', 'g', 'o'},
            {'t', 'r', 'm', 'l', 'p'}
    };
    private static int dim_x = matrix.length;
    private static int dim_y = matrix[matrix.length -1].length;
    private static Set<String> wordSet = new HashSet<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //dictionary
        wordSet.add("after");
        wordSet.add("hate");
        wordSet.add("hair");
        wordSet.add("air");
        wordSet.add("eat");
        wordSet.add("tea");

        for (int x = 0; x < dim_x; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < dim_y; y++) {
                checkAndPrint(matrix[x][y] + "");
                int[][] visitedMap = new int[dim_x][dim_y];
                visitedMap[x][y] = 1;
                recursion(matrix[x][y] + "", visitedMap, x, y);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void checkAndPrint(String word) {
        if (wordSet.contains(word)) {
            System.out.println(word);
        }
    }

    private static void recursion(String word, int[][] visitedMap, int x, int y) {
        for (int i = Math.max(x - 1, 0); i < Math.min(x + 2, dim_x); i++) {
            for (int j = Math.max(y - 1, 0); j < Math.min(y + 2, dim_y); j++) {
                if (visitedMap[i][j] == 1) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    int[][] newVisitedMap = new int[dim_x][dim_y];
                    for (int p = 0; p < dim_x; p++) {
                        for (int q = 0; q < dim_y; q++) {
                           newVisitedMap[p][q] = visitedMap[p][q];
                        }
                    }
                    newVisitedMap[i][j] = 1;
                    checkAndPrint(word + matrix[i][j]);
                    recursion(word + matrix[i][j], newVisitedMap, i, j);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * @author Sujeet Kumar (mrsujeet@gmail.com) It prints out all strings that can
 *         be formed by moving left, right, up, down, or diagonally and exist in
 *         a given dictionary , without repeating any cell. Assumes words are
 *         comprised of lower case letters. Currently prints words as many times
 *         as they appear, not just once. *
 */

public class BoggleGame 
{
  /* A sample 4X4 board/2D matrix */
  private static char[][] board = { { 's', 'a', 's', 'g' },
                                  { 'a', 'u', 't', 'h' }, 
                                  { 'r', 't', 'j', 'e' },
                                  { 'k', 'a', 'h', 'e' }
};

/* A sample dictionary which contains unique collection of words */
private static Set<String> dictionary = new HashSet<String>();

private static boolean[][] visited = new boolean[board.length][board[0].length];

public static void main(String[] arg) {
    dictionary.add("sujeet");
    dictionary.add("sarthak");
    findWords();

}

// show all words, starting from each possible starting place
private static void findWords() {
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            dfs(i, j, buffer);
        }

    }

}

// run depth first search starting at cell (i, j)
private static void dfs(int i, int j, StringBuffer buffer) {
    /*
     * base case: just return in recursive call when index goes out of the
     * size of matrix dimension
     */
    if (i < 0 || j < 0 || i > board.length - 1 || j > board[i].length - 1) {
        return;
    }

    /*
     * base case: to return in recursive call when given cell is already
     * visited in a given string of word
     */
    if (visited[i][j] == true) { // can't visit a cell more than once
        return;
    }

    // not to allow a cell to reuse
    visited[i][j] = true;

    // combining cell character with other visited cells characters to form
    // word a potential word which may exist in dictionary
    buffer.append(board[i][j]);

    // found a word in dictionary. Print it.
    if (dictionary.contains(buffer.toString())) {
        System.out.println(buffer);
    }

    /*
     * consider all neighbors.For a given cell considering all adjacent
     * cells in horizontal, vertical and diagonal direction
     */
    for (int k = i - 1; k <= i + 1; k++) {
        for (int l = j - 1; l <= j + 1; l++) {
            dfs(k, l, buffer);

        }

    }
    buffer.deleteCharAt(buffer.length() - 1);
    visited[i][j] = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Surrounding your code by some explanation would seriously improve your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with for solving the boggle problem. I guess it is the most "pythonic" way to do things:

```
from itertools import combinations
from itertools import izip
from math import fabs

def isAllowedStep(current,step,length,doubleLength):
            # for step == length -1 not to be 0 => trivial solutions are not allowed
    return length > 1 and \
           current + step < doubleLength and current - step > 0 and \
           ( step == 1 or step == -1 or step <= length+1 or step >= length - 1)

def getPairwiseList(someList):
    iterableList = iter(someList)
    return izip(iterableList, iterableList)

def isCombinationAllowed(combination,length,doubleLength):

    for (first,second) in  getPairwiseList(combination):
        _, firstCoordinate = first
        _, secondCoordinate = second
        if not isAllowedStep(firstCoordinate, fabs(secondCoordinate-firstCoordinate),length,doubleLength):
            return False
    return True

def extractSolution(combinations):
    return ["".join([x[0] for x in combinationTuple]) for combinationTuple in combinations]


length = 4
text = tuple("".join("fxie amlo ewbx astu".split()))
textIndices = tuple(range(len(text)))
coordinates = zip(text,textIndices)

validCombinations = [combination for combination in combinations(coordinates,length) if isCombinationAllowed(combination,length,length*length)]
solution = extractSolution(validCombinations)
```

**This part I kindly advise you not to use for all the possible matches** but it would actually provide a possibility to check if the words you have generated actually constitue valid words:

```
import mechanize
def checkWord(word):
    url = "https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/search?filter=dictionary&query="+word
    br = mechanize.Browser()
    br.set_handle_robots(False)
    response = br.open(url)
    text = response.read()
    return "no exact matches"  not in text.lower()

print [valid for valid in solution[:10] if checkWord(valid)]
```