# Is there a corpus of English words in nltk?

Tags: nltk

Is there any way to get the list of English words in python nltk library?
I tried to find it but the only thing I have found is `wordnet` from `nltk.corpus`. But [based on documentation,](http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html) it does not have what I need (it finds synonyms for a word).

I know how to find the list of this words by myself (this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/772929/1090562) covers it in details), so I am interested whether I can do this by only using nltk library.

Comment: For those still having issues but in need to use one NLTK, here you can copy paste one: https://www.ranks.nl/stopwords

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Yes, `from nltk.corpus import words`

And check using:

```
>>> "fine" in words.words()
True
```

Reference: Section 4.1 (Wordlist Corpora), chapter 2 of [Natural Language Processing with Python](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch02.html).

Comment: thank you, but can you please where can you found it in documentation (looks like I somehow missed it)?

Comment: @SalvadorDali Have added the reference.

Comment: Missing some fairly common words, especially plural words

Comment: Since words.words() takes considerable time and returns a list instead of a set, in practice it's much faster to cache it when initializing: vocab = set(words.words())

Comment: @Tahlor that's right. Hence the need to test it for a second time after lemmatizing the word.

Answer (score 19):

Other than the `nltk.corpus.words` that @salvadordali has highlighted,:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import words
>>> print words.readme()
Wordlists

en: English, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Words_(Unix)
en-basic: 850 English words: C.K. Ogden in The ABC of Basic English (1932)
>>> print words.words()[:10]
[u'A', u'a', u'aa', u'aal', u'aalii', u'aam', u'Aani', u'aardvark', u'aardwolf', u'Aaron']
```

Do note that `nltk.corpus.words` is a list of words without frequencies so it's not exactly a corpora of natural text.

The `corpus` package that contains various corpora, some of which are English corpora, see http://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/. E.g. `nltk.corpus.brown`:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import brown
>>> brown.words()[:10]
[u'The', u'Fulton', u'County', u'Grand', u'Jury', u'said', u'Friday', u'an', u'investigation', u'of']
```

To get a word list from a natural text corpus:

```
>>> wordlist = set(brown.words())
>>> print len(wordlist)
56057
>>> wordlist_lowercased = set(i.lower() for i in brown.words())
>>> print len(wordlist_lowercased)
49815
```

Note that the `brown.words()` contains words with both lower and upper cases like natural text.

In most cases, a list of words is not very useful without frequencies, so you can use the `FreqDist`:

```
>>> from nltk import FreqDist
>>> from nltk.corpus import brown
>>> frequency_list = FreqDist(i.lower() for i in brown.words())
>>> frequency_list.most_common()[:10]
[(u'the', 69971), (u',', 58334), (u'.', 49346), (u'of', 36412), (u'and', 28853), (u'to', 26158), (u'a', 23195), (u'in', 21337), (u'that', 10594), (u'is', 10109)]
```

For more, see http://www.nltk.org/book/ch01.html on how to access corpora and process them in NLTK