# Get all leaf words for a stemmed keyword

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am looking for something like un-stemming. Is there a way to get all possible list of words which have share a common stem. Something like

```
>>> get_leaf_words('play')
>>> ['player', 'play', 'playing' ... ]
```

Comment: From what data?

Comment: maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56978661/is-there-a-way-to-reverse-stem-in-python-nltk

Comment: @AntonPomieshchenko i saw this.. I was however looking for something more generic

Comment: @schwobaseggl i am looking for something independent to the domain.

Comment: That would be generally infinite, wouldn't it?

Comment: @schwobaseggl Standard English corpus will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution to the above question: https://github.com/gutfeeling/word_forms ! Thanks to @Divyanshu Srivastava

```
>>> from word_forms.word_forms import get_word_forms
>>> get_word_forms("president")
>>> {'n': {'presidents', 'presidentships', 'presidencies', 'presidentship', 'president', 'presidency'},
     'a': {'presidential'},
     'v': {'preside', 'presided', 'presiding', 'presides'},
     'r': {'presidentially'}}
>>> get_word_forms("elect")
>>> {'n': {'elects', 'electives', 'electors', 'elect', 'eligibilities', 'electorates', 'eligibility', 'elector', 'election', 'elections', 'electorate', 'elective'},
     'a': {'eligible', 'electoral', 'elective', 'elect'},
     'v': {'electing', 'elects', 'elected', 'elect'},
     'r': set()}
```

---

---

Previous Answer:

Reverse stemming is not possible, as most of the stemmers create the base word using some rule-set applied on the original word.

But there is revere lemmatization which is called realization (or "surface realization").

You can use some of the publically available lemmatization datasets/dictionaries to do that.

Example: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-opennlp-auto-tagging/master/src/main/resources/models/en-lemmatizer.dict [Apache OpenNLP]

I could not find a direct library in Python but found one in Java ([pynlg](https://github.com/mapado/pynlg))

Furthermore: If you have enough original words, you can create a reverse dictionary for lemmatization OR stemming!

Comment: @Divyanshu Let me know if you find anything, I will update it here! This sounds like an interesting problem, I will be working on a python library for this (but that might take time)

Comment: Came acreoss this code on github.. this is actually what i wanted. https://github.com/gutfeeling/word_forms