# Select Cells On A Table By Dragging

Tags: javascript

I was looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746082/how-to-find-list-of-possible-words-from-a-letter-matrix-boggle-solver) and saw the reference to the iPhone game where you drag across the screen selecting letters as you go.

I was curious to see an implimentation of this in Javascript using tables. So you'd drag the mouse over each cell they would then become highlighted.

I'm not sure what the best method would be but I hope someone has a go. Someone attempted it [here](http://grover.open2space.com/sites/default/files/articles/dom/test.htm), but it doesn't really work.

[image] [image]

*Thank [Cacoo](https://cacoo.com/) for the sexy diagrams. It's like an online visio, really nice. Check it out ;)*

Comment: Interesting challenge (and diagrams). The trick will be to prevent the default text selection in the browser...

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Here's a working prototype: http://jsfiddle.net/few5E/ Using jQuery for DOM hooking, but could easily be implemented with another framework.

A few relevant facts:

- The mousedown event of the table cells is hooked to track the actual click. This event is stopped, so that text selection is hindered. Also binding ontextselect for the same effect in IE.
- The mouseover event will toggle the highlighted class for the cell
- The mouseout event is hooked on `document`. This is to ensure that it always runs. If the mouseup event was hooked on the table cell, it would not trigger if you released the mouse key with the mouse outside of the table. This state is tracked in `isMouseDown`.

Full source code for reference:

```js
$(function () {
  var isMouseDown = false,
    isHighlighted;
  $("#our_table td")
    .mousedown(function () {
      isMouseDown = true;
      $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
      isHighlighted = $(this).hasClass("highlighted");
      return false; // prevent text selection
    })
    .mouseover(function () {
      if (isMouseDown) {
        $(this).toggleClass("highlighted", isHighlighted);
      }
    })
    .bind("selectstart", function () {
      return false;
    })

  $(document)
    .mouseup(function () {
      isMouseDown = false;
    });
});
```

```css
table td {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  background-color:#ccc;
  border:1px solid #fff;
}

table td.highlighted {
  background-color:#999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="our_table">
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>e</td>
    <td>f</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>g</td>
    <td>h</td>
    <td>i</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Update**: http://jsfiddle.net/Brv6J/ a slightly different version - the highlighted state will only change when you release and click again.

**Update 2**: http://jsfiddle.net/Brv6J/3/ - binding onselectstart so that text is not selected in IE.

Comment: Interesting that you use toggleClass... in this case, when you hover back to a cell that's already selected, this removes the selection. This may or may not be correct based on application logic. Intuitively (and as I do in my solution), I keep all selected until mouseup.

Comment: See alternate link :) Just added it.

Comment: The use of toggleClass is just a hack, so to speak. In a proper unit testable implementation, you would use an instance with a boolean, or something like that.

Comment: Also, changing the state logic so that it will de-select everything on mouseup (that's what you describe, right?) is trivial. A `$("#our_table td").removeClass("highlighted")` on the mouseup event would be the appropriate hack in this case.

Comment: For those who want this to work on newly created Tables (via ajax), see this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Brv6J/803/)**: http://jsfiddle.net/Brv6J/803/

Comment: None of Augusts solutions work anymore in Google Chrome from my point of view. Safari the same. But the solution posted by @MackieeE works for me.

Comment: any examples on how to implement this with touch support?

Comment: Shouldn't be too hard to hook up the events using http://hammerjs.github.io/ instead of the native "mousedown" events etc used here.

Comment: Any way to make this work for (vertically) long tables? If you add a couple more <tr>-s, the table/page doesn't automatically scroll down and select further down...

Comment: add `if (event.button === 2) return false;` to disable right click from affecting selection at the beginning of the `mousedown` event and don't forget to add `event` as a parameter

Comment: Holy hell what a nice tiny snippit of code to get this to work. Thanks.

Comment: Not working properly if mouse pointer drags fast on the table row of small height. '27px'

Answer (score 19):

If you're after spreadsheet-like cell selection (in column/row blocks), you need to highlight every cell in every row that is between your start & end index (both row and cell) in your mouseover event.

As the user might start selecting cells from all directions (up-bottom, bottom-up, right-left, left-right) you need to assign the correct indexes for start & end.

```js
var table = $("#table");    

var isMouseDown = false;
var startRowIndex = null;
var startCellIndex = null;

function selectTo(cell) {
    
    var row = cell.parent();    
    var cellIndex = cell.index();
    var rowIndex = row.index();
    
    var rowStart, rowEnd, cellStart, cellEnd;
    
    if (rowIndex < startRowIndex) {
        rowStart = rowIndex;
        rowEnd = startRowIndex;
    } else {
        rowStart = startRowIndex;
        rowEnd = rowIndex;
    }
    
    if (cellIndex < startCellIndex) {
        cellStart = cellIndex;
        cellEnd = startCellIndex;
    } else {
        cellStart = startCellIndex;
        cellEnd = cellIndex;
    }        
    
    for (var i = rowStart; i <= rowEnd; i++) {
        var rowCells = table.find("tr").eq(i).find("td");
        for (var j = cellStart; j <= cellEnd; j++) {
            rowCells.eq(j).addClass("selected");
        }        
    }
}

table.find("td").mousedown(function (e) {
    isMouseDown = true;
    var cell = $(this);

    table.find(".selected").removeClass("selected"); // deselect everything
    
    if (e.shiftKey) {
        selectTo(cell);                
    } else {
        cell.addClass("selected");
        startCellIndex = cell.index();
        startRowIndex = cell.parent().index();
    }
    
    return false; // prevent text selection
})
.mouseover(function () {
    if (!isMouseDown) return;
    table.find(".selected").removeClass("selected");
    selectTo($(this));
})
.bind("selectstart", function () {
    return false;
});

$(document).mouseup(function () {
    isMouseDown = false;
});
```

```css
table td {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    width: 80px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 10px;
}

td.selected {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
Click and drag mouse or use shift key to select cells.
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>    
</table>
```

Comment: Better, you'd use Dojo or jQuery (or something even higher-level)

Comment: Add `table.find(".selected").removeClass("selected");` in the `mouseover` function to make it more spreadsheet-like i.e. deselect cells when moving over a selected area. Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chechs/qvw0pgcu/22/)

Comment: This is great, works with shift-selection. Would be amazing if it supported ctrl-selection as well.