# Multiple Cells Selection in Table in html

Tags: javascript, html, cells

Im trying to have a mulitple selection of cells in a table in html

Ex : 
I have a 4x4 table matrix 
And im trying to Select multiple cells

Also is it possible to create a dragable selection box around the table in order to select them

Is this possible if so can we only use javascript and css to accomplish this or do we need other softwares also

Thanks

Comment: it'd be easier and cleaner if you use jquery which has good library of plugins to do the exact work you want.

Comment: [Here][1] I've answered traditional spreadsheet-like cell selection. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31876373/760923

Answer (score 2):

```
$("td").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("Selected");
});
```

Then just use a css class called Selected to highlight them with your style of choice.

use `$(".Selected")` to get all selected cells

If you insist on not using jQuery then

```
var addEvent = function(event, elem, f) {
    if (elem.attachEvent) {
        elem.attachEvent("on" + event, f);
    } else {
        elem.addEventListener(event, f, false);
    }
};

var addClass = function(elem, className) {
    if (elem.className.indexOf(className) == -1) {
        elem.className += " " + className;
    } else {
        elem.className = elem.className.replace(" " + className, "");    
    }
};

var addSelected = function() {
    addClass(this, "Selected");
};

var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

for (var i = 0, elem = tds[i]; i < tds.length; elem = tds[++i]) {
    addEvent("click", elem, addSelected);
}
```

See live [example](http://jsfiddle.net/KMFvW/)

Comment: he is reluctant to use jquery :) he wants only javascript!!

Comment: @Shrinath see how not using jQuery involves writing your own DOM manipulation utility functions?

Comment: @Raynos : LoL :D if it wasn't for jquery, plain old JS would be PITA :)

Comment: @Shrinath JS is fine. The problem is cross-browser compliance. If I didn't use jQuery I would have a library of similar size to jQuery written by hand and less efficient.

Comment: Hey thank you all for your quick response , just wanted to know if i could see a working example of this it would be of gr8 help

Comment: @Anoop fixed the code from some bugs and added a live example. (It even passes JSLint!)

Comment: AWESOME!!! Nice work Ray... works perfect , Just wanted to know if we can also have a kinda selction box on the table which will select the cells