# A Real jQuery "Grid"

Tags: jquery, drag

I am currently looking for a solution to a real jQuery "grid."

Every table plugin I have found so far has the same kind of structure and usage ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159025/jquery-grid-recommendations ) They all have headers, different buttons, and many more different functions. Yet all of these can be  related more to an excel worksheet- which I don't consider a grid- and is something I am not looking for.

The closest solution I have found for a grid with the layout and the ability to select and drag is found here: [Select Cells On A Table By Dragging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013902/select-cells-on-a-table-by-dragging)

As you can see in those two images attached in that post

[image: http://i.imgur.com/UIMwD.png]

[image: http://imgur.com/ZfFVu.png]

The grid is more like a game board/tiled based.

What I am looking for is a jQuery plugin that makes a real tiled based grid  and allows for selecting/drag-to-select functionality, along with (hopefully) a event response to the selection.

I have a custom built table currently made, and I am having trouble adding more functionality with it since the lack of support for different plugins pertaining to dragging and selecting. I have tried implementing this drag to select plugin (http://andreaslagerkvist.com/jquery/drag-to-select/) and have not been able to make it work with a table.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried using the game board you mentioned and modifying it to suit your needs?

Comment: I mentioned the idea of a game board... I haven't actually found one.

Comment: I was referring to the post on selecting cells on a table by dragging. There is an answer in there that seems to work pretty well. I guess I'm still not quite clear what it is you need.

Comment: Sadly, "grid" has been stolen to mean "spreadsheet-like editor". :-(

Comment: @redEVo I'm looking more for the selecting ability of http://andreaslagerkvist.com/jquery/drag-to-select/ - I don't have to drag over every cell to highlight.. only general.

Comment: Are you on Google+ yet? There is something in the photos section where you can drag to select elements. It seems to work pretty well. I doubt they use jQuery but whatever it is might be worth looking into.

Comment: Ditto, also looking for this, as a basis for grid-based puzzle games...

Comment: Update: I'm now officially working on one of these myself. It will actually be part of a crowd-funding campaign shortly. I'll post it when it's ready. I intend to make a game but make the grid-game engine beneath it open-source. Stay tuned... if interested in being involved, click thru to my user page, and web page, and send the webmaster an email.

Answer (score -1):

If you really "only" need a grid of fixed sized, evenly distributed elements, just create the right amount of `div` elements and position them with `.offset( coordinates )`

**[EDIT]** I'm not aware of any plugins which do what you need. That doesn't mean there isn't one. Try to google.

If that fails, have a look at one of the JavaScript game engines like [gamequery](http://gamequery.onaluf.org/). For the drag&drop support, look into the UI extensions of jQuery.

Comment: This doesn't answer the non-trivial part of the question "What I am looking for is a jQuery plugin that makes a real tiled based grid and allows for selecting/drag-to-select functionality, along with (hopefully) a event response to the selection."