# Select all td's over multiple rows based on selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to select all td's within my table with a drag event. What I am trying to achieve is to create a date range based on my first selected td, until the last selected td, but they can span over multiple rows.
At the moment, I am using `nextUntil()` with `andSelf()` to include the last selected, but it only selects td's within the current tr.
Below is a sample of my code.
Any help please.

```
this.BindCalendarMouseDrag = function () {
        var isMouseDown = false;
        var isHighlighted;
        var selectedDays = [];
        $(".tabCalendarContainer tr.trCalWeek td")
            .mousedown(function () {
                isMouseDown = true;
                $(this).addClass("highlighted");
                isHighlighted = $(this).hasClass("highlighted");
                selectedDays.push($(this));
                return false; // prevent text selection
            })
            .mouseover(function () {
                if (isMouseDown) {
                    $(this).addClass("highlighted", isHighlighted);

                    var firstSelectedDay = selectedDays[0];
                    firstSelectedDay.nextUntil($(this)).andSelf().add($(this)).addClass("highlighted", isHighlighted);

                    selectedDays.push($(this));
                }
            })
            .bind("selectstart", function () {
                return false;
            });

        $(document).mouseup(function () {
            isMouseDown = false;
            //alert(selectedDays.length);
        });
    };
```

Comment: A jsfiddle would be most helpful here to get a better idea of what you want and how to solve it.

Comment: Try using jQuery UI Selectable, it should work a lot better.

Comment: I've developed such widget once, so a word of notice here: that approach (using mouseover) may be slow and unreliable (e.g. mouseover events aren't always fired - if user is quick to move his mouse some of the td's may be left-out. In my solution I ended up using mouse position at dragstart and dragend to calculate which td's should be highlighted.

Comment: How large is the table you're trying to work with here? Is is like range in month selector (you have around 30 cells) or is it more like 356 cells to cover?

Comment: It is a normal calendar month view WTK. So you're looking at 35-42 cells depending on the number of weeks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select Cells On A Table By Dragging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013902/select-cells-on-a-table-by-dragging)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the liberty of constructing a fiddle that illustrates a calendar with draggable weekdays. It doesn't cater for BACKWARDS dragging yet, but you should be able to easily adjust the code to accommodate it.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("td.week").hover(
        function () { $(this).addClass("hover"); },
        function () { $(this).removeClass("hover"); }
    );
    var busySelecting = false;
    var selectedDays = [];
    var contains = function(day) {
        for (var d in selectedDays) {
            if (selectedDays[d].text() == day.text())
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    };
    $("td.week").mousedown(function () {
        selectedDays = [];
        $("td.week").removeClass("selected");
        busySelecting = true;
        if ($(this).text() != "") {
            $(this).addClass("selected");
            selectedDays.push($(this));
        }
        return false;
    });
    $("td.week").mouseover(function () {
        if (busySelecting &&
           $(this).text() != "")
        {
            var busyHovering = $(this);
            $("td.week").each(function () {
                if ($(this).text() != "" &&
                    parseInt($(this).text(),10) > parseInt(selectedDays[0].text(),10) &&
                    parseInt($(this).text(),10) <= parseInt(busyHovering.text(),10) &&
                    !contains($(this))) {
                    $(this).addClass("selected");
                    selectedDays.push($(this));                
                }
            });
            $(selectedDays).each(function () {
                if (parseInt($(this).text(),10) > parseInt(busyHovering.text(),10)) {
                    $(this).removeClass("selected");
                    selectedDays.pop($(this));
                }
            });
            selectedDays.push($(this));
        }
    });
    $(document).mouseup(function () {
        busySelecting = false;
        alert("You selected the following range: " +
              selectedDays[0].text() + " - " +
              selectedDays[selectedDays.length - 1].text());
    });
});
```

```css
td
{
    padding:10px;
    cursor:default;
}
td.hover
{
    background:#EEE;
}
td.weekend
{
    background:silver;
}
td.selected
{
    background:#5EE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="weekend"></td>
        <td class="week"></td>
        <td class="week">1</td>
        <td class="week">2</td>
        <td class="week">3</td>
        <td class="week">4</td>
        <td class="weekend">5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="weekend">6</td>
        <td class="week">7</td>
        <td class="week">8</td>
        <td class="week">9</td>
        <td class="week">10</td>
        <td class="week">11</td>
        <td class="weekend">12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="weekend">13</td>
        <td class="week">14</td>
        <td class="week">15</td>
        <td class="week">16</td>
        <td class="week">17</td>
        <td class="week">18</td>
        <td class="weekend">19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="weekend">20</td>
        <td class="week">21</td>
        <td class="week">22</td>
        <td class="week">23</td>
        <td class="week">24</td>
        <td class="week">25</td>
        <td class="weekend">26</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="weekend">27</td>
        <td class="week">28</td>
        <td class="week">29</td>
        <td class="week">30</td>
        <td class="week">31</td>
        <td class="week"></td>
        <td class="weekend"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Farlig, I'll have a look at your solution.

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Thanks Farlig.