# Convert jQuery click/drag code to React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

With the code below, taken from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17489647/1417223), a user can select cells vertically in a grid by click-and-drag.

I intend to use this functionality in React and thus need to convert it to a component.

How would one change the method-chaining and selector based structure to React?

[Working example with jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/daver182/cB4UQ/1/)

```
--HTML--

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="our_table">
  <tr>
    <td data-row="1" data-col="1">a</td>
    <td data-row="1" data-col="2">b</td>
    <td data-row="1" data-col="3">c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-row="2" data-col="1">d</td>
    <td data-row="2" data-col="2">e</td>
    <td data-row="2" data-col="3">f</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-row="3" data-col="1">g</td>
    <td data-row="3" data-col="2">h</td>
    <td data-row="3" data-col="3">i</td>
  </tr>
</table>

--CSS--

table td {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  background-color:#ccc;
  border:1px solid #fff;
}

table td.highlighted {
  background-color:#999;
}

--jQuery--

$(function () {
  var isMouseDown = false,
    isHighlighted;
 var currentCol;
  $("#our_table td")
    .mousedown(function () {
      isMouseDown = true;
      currentCol = this.getAttribute("data-col");
      $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
      isHighlighted = $(this).hasClass("highlighted");
      return false; // prevent text selection
    })
    .mouseover(function () {
      if (isMouseDown) {
          if(currentCol === this.getAttribute("data-col")){
              $(this).toggleClass("highlighted", isHighlighted);
          }
      }
    })
    .bind("selectstart", function () {
      return false;
    })

  $(document)
    .mouseup(function () {
      isMouseDown = false;
    });
});
```

Comment: You'd add listeners on the components themselves, pass everything else through as props and look for the changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All what you need is in [React Event System docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html). *onMouseDown*, *onMouseUp* and *onMouseOver* are the most interesting event handlers for you. I created [Similar Example](http://jsfiddle.net/74t2ovqh/1/).

In `componentWillReceiveProps` function I check if the cell should update their own state and I use `shouldComponentUpdate` to prevent rendering the component if it's not needed (it's very important when you have a lot of cells). The main state is in `Hello` (parent) component: `overId` contains cell data, `startedId` contains starting cell and `enableSelect` is true when we start selection.

It's "similar" because I didn't check your example carefully, but I think it's good enough to show you how it's works.