# Multiple selection of items

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to know how I can make a multiple selection of elements "li", I have the following, where gender vertically hours, and want to make a multiple selection of hours taken

```
<ul class="list-group">
<li class="list-group-item col-md-12 "  
ng-repeat="h_m in [] | tiempoTabla:8:16:15" 
style="padding: 1px !important" 
ng-class="activo(h_m)" 
ng-click="$root.tab[1].active = true">
<p  class="hora text-center" style=" margin: inherit"   >{{h_m}} </p></li>
</ul>
```

[image]

I found selected with jquery, but as angular take the $ index?
http://jsfiddle.net/pqF7b/

Comment: Do you want do drag-n-select or you allowed to simply click-n-select?

Comment: at this time temporarily solve the problem, each cell selected, but will crawl would be much better

Comment: try this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013902/select-cells-on-a-table-by-dragging