# Giving a pair of numbers as a parameter in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746082/how-to-find-list-of-possible-words-from-a-letter-matrix-boggle-solver/750012#750012) message, the author has written

```
def neighbors((x, y)):
```

When I tried to run this with Python 3.3, it told me that it is invalid syntax. How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution is to do:

```
def neighbors(point):
    x, y = point
```

This feature was removed from 3.x, for [a range of reasons](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/).

Comment: Thanks! The quickest answer on StackOverflow I've ever seen. You need to wait a few minutes before I can accept it.

Comment: No worries! Just as a note, it's always worth waiting for a bit before accepting. You never know if someone will come along and give some insightful, amazing answer, which you might not get if you accept early and people stop looking at the question. In this case, I think I've covered it, but just a note.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to write it as

```
def neighbors(x, y):
```

and replace:

```
for (nx, ny) in neighbors(path[-1]):
```

with

```
for (nx, ny) in neighbors(*path[-1]):
```