# Finding word possibilities in a PHP array

Tags: php

I'm currently working on a word game and I need to find word possibilities in a 4x4 array.

Here's what the array looks like:

```
   0 1 2 3
  --------
0| d r o k
1| b o v l
2| u o y t
3| p e x i
```

The player can only combine adjacent letters. 
Example: The word "book" will be `[0,1][1,1][2,0][3,0]`

What's the fastest way to do this?
And by the way. I only need to know if the word is possible to make or not witch means a function to return true or false would be enough. something like this: validateWord($array, $word)
Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you try already......?

Comment: Fastest way would be to map the grid as an adjacency grid

Comment: so is the problem now the combining (that you automatically combine the letters) or the finding if it is a possible word from a list of possible words?

Comment: Given that letters must be connected, the Union Find algorithm springs to mind

Comment: [0,1][1,1][2,0][3,0] will represent 'roup' not 'book'

Comment: I found this code on Stackoverflow but when I try to run it I get an error saying the 7th argument is missing.
I gave it $words as the 7th argument but I get an empty array.

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746082/how-to-find-list-of-possible-words-from-a-letter-matrix-boggle-solver#757165)

Comment: Anyone? Any lead will be appreciated..