# Boggle - count all possible paths on a N*N grid. Performance

Tags: algorithm, optimization, f#, time-complexity, boggle

While reading up [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746082/how-to-find-list-of-possible-words-from-a-letter-matrix-boggle-solver), I wondered why no one would "simply" iterate all the possible paths on the boggle grid and have the word-tries follow and then cancel the path if there is no match in the word-trie. Cannot be that many paths on a tiny 4 by 4 grid, right? How many paths are there? So I set out to code a path-counter function in F#. The results yield what no one stated on that other page: Way more paths on the grid than I would have guessed (more paths than words in the word-set, actually).

While all that is pretty much the back story to my question, the code I ended up with was running rather slow and I found that I could not give good answers to a few aspects of the code. So here, the code first, then below it, you will find points which I think deserve explanations...

```
let moves n state square =
    let allSquares = [0..n*n-1] |> Set.ofList
    let right = Set.difference allSquares (Set.ofList [n-1..n..n*n])
    let left = Set.difference allSquares (Set.ofList [0..n..n*n-1])
    let up = Set.difference allSquares (Set.ofList [0..n-1])
    let down = Set.difference allSquares (Set.ofList [n*n-n..n*n-1])
    let downRight = Set.intersect right down
    let downLeft = Set.intersect left down
    let upRight = Set.intersect right up
    let upLeft = Set.intersect left up
    let appendIfInSet se v res =
        if Set.contains square se then res @ v else res
    []
    |> appendIfInSet right [square + 1]
    |> appendIfInSet left [square - 1]
    |> appendIfInSet up [square - n]
    |> appendIfInSet down [square + n]
    |> appendIfInSet downRight [square + n + 1]
    |> appendIfInSet downLeft [square + n - 1]
    |> appendIfInSet upRight [square - n + 1]
    |> appendIfInSet upLeft [square - n - 1]
    |> List.choose (fun s -> if ((uint64 1 <<< s) &&& state) = 0UL then Some s else None )

let block state square =
    state ||| (uint64 1 <<< square)

let countAllPaths n lmin lmax =
    let mov = moves n                 // line 30
    let rec count l state sq c =
        let state' = block state sq
        let m = mov state' sq
        match l with
        | x when x <= lmax && x >= lmin ->
            List.fold (fun acc s -> count (l+1) state' s acc) (c+1) m
        | x when x < lmin ->
            List.fold (fun acc s -> count (l+1) state' s acc) (c) m
        | _ ->
            c
    List.fold (fun acc s -> count 0 (block 0UL s) s acc) 0 [0..n*n-1]

[<EntryPoint>] 
let main args =
    printfn "%d: %A" (Array.length args) args
    if 3 = Array.length args then
        let n = int args.[0]
        let lmin = int args.[1]
        let lmax = int args.[2]
        printfn "%d %d %d -> %d" n lmin lmax (countAllPaths n lmin lmax)
    else
        printfn "usage: wordgames.exe n lmin lmax"
    0
```

1. In line 30, I curried the `moves` function with the first argument, hoping that maybe code optimization would benefit from it. Maybe optimizing the 9 sets I create in move which are only a function of `n`. After all, they need not be generated over and over again, right? On the other hand, I would not really bet on it actually happening.
   So, question #1 is: How could I enforce this optimization in an as little code bloating way as possible? (I could of course create a type with 9 members and then an array of that type for each possible n and then do a look up table like usage of the pre-computed sets but that would be code bloat in my opinion).
2. Many sources hint that parallel folds are considered critical. How could I create a parallel version of the counting function (which runs on multiple cores)?
3. Does anyone have clever ideas how to speed this up? Maybe some pruning or memoization etc?

At first, when I ran the function for `n=4 lmin=3 lmax=8` I thought it takes so long because I ran it in fsi. But then I compiled the code with -O and it still took about the same time...

**UPDATE**

While waiting for input from you guys, I did the code bloated manual optimization version (runs much faster) and then found a way to make it run on multiple cores.
All in all those 2 changes yielded about a speed up by a factor of 30. Here the (bloated) version I came up with (still looking for a way to avoid the bloat):

```
let squareSet n =
    let allSquares = [0..n*n-1] |> Set.ofList
    let right = Set.difference allSquares (Set.ofList [n-1..n..n*n])
    let left = Set.difference allSquares (Set.ofList [0..n..n*n-1])
    let up = Set.difference allSquares (Set.ofList [0..n-1])
    let down = Set.difference allSquares (Set.ofList [n*n-n..n*n-1])
    let downRight = Set.intersect right down
    let downLeft = Set.intersect left down
    let upRight = Set.intersect right up
    let upLeft = Set.intersect left up
    [|right;left;up;down;upRight;upLeft;downRight;downLeft|]    

let RIGHT,LEFT,UP,DOWN = 0,1,2,3
let UPRIGHT,UPLEFT,DOWNRIGHT,DOWNLEFT = 4,5,6,7

let squareSets =
    [|Set.empty;Set.empty;Set.empty;Set.empty;Set.empty;Set.empty;Set.empty;Set.empty;|]
    ::
    [    for i in 1..8 do
            yield squareSet i
    ]
    |> Array.ofList


let moves n state square =
    let appendIfInSet se v res =
        if Set.contains square se then res @ v else res

    []
    |> appendIfInSet squareSets.[n].[RIGHT] [square + 1]
    |> appendIfInSet squareSets.[n].[LEFT] [square - 1]
    |> appendIfInSet squareSets.[n].[UP] [square - n]
    |> appendIfInSet squareSets.[n].[DOWN] [square + n]
    |> appendIfInSet squareSets.[n].[DOWNRIGHT] [square + n + 1]
    |> appendIfInSet squareSets.[n].[DOWNLEFT] [square + n - 1]
    |> appendIfInSet squareSets.[n].[UPRIGHT] [square - n + 1]
    |> appendIfInSet squareSets.[n].[UPLEFT] [square - n - 1]
    |> List.choose (fun s -> if ((uint64 1 <<< s) &&& state) = 0UL then Some s else None )

let block state square =
    state ||| (uint64 1 <<< square)

let countAllPaths n lmin lmax =
    let mov = moves n
    let rec count l state sq c =
        let state' = block state sq
        let m = mov state' sq
        match l with
        | x when x <= lmax && x >= lmin ->
            List.fold (fun acc s -> count (l+1) state' s acc) (c+1) m
        | x when x < lmin ->
            List.fold (fun acc s -> count (l+1) state' s acc) (c) m
        | _ ->
            c
    //List.fold (fun acc s -> count 0 (block 0UL s) s acc) 0 [0..n*n-1]
    [0..n*n-1]
    |> Array.ofList
    |> Array.Parallel.map (fun start -> count 0 (block 0UL start) start 0)
    |> Array.sum

[<EntryPoint>] 
let main args =
    printfn "%d: %A" (Array.length args) args
    if 3 = Array.length args then
        let n = int args.[0]
        let lmin = int args.[1]
        let lmax = int args.[2]
        printfn "%d %d %d -> %d" n lmin lmax (countAllPaths n lmin lmax)
    else
        printfn "usage: wordgames.exe n lmin lmax"
    0
```

Comment: It seems that the question is more suitable for [CR](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/f%23)

Comment: @FoggyFinder Create a huge enough number of Stack Exchange sites and no question is suitable for any of them. At CR they could argue that it does not fit because the performance footprint is not acceptable and refer to StackOverflow. Just saying, this discussion is not really helpful...

Comment: If you are just trying to count the number of paths, then why not come at it as a math equation and solve, e.g. do it with pen and paper? One of the first questions I ask myself with solving a problem is that `Is a computer the best way to solve the problem?`. In other words a computer is just another tool as is a pen and paper.

Comment: Of interest: [Boggle on GitHub](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=boggle&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults) This seems to be a very popular homework problem / learning example.

Comment: @GuyCoder Yes I also wonder if there is a analytical (formula) solution to it. Is there one? Can you show us? That would indeed be the fastest way to implement it. My first question usually is: Where do I have to think more and longer? Programming it or trying my mediocre math skills? ;)

Comment: I fond this question interesting. I started drawing trees with pen and paper which lead to either considering building up the count, or building the full tree without constraints and then removing based on the constraints which lead me to looking at solutions using Prolog which is where I am at now. I am also leaving the equation based on `N` as you noted. This may take a while and I don't know if I have the time to reach a result, but if I do I will post it.

Comment: Of interest: [Rules of Boggle](http://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/boggle.pdf)

Comment: Of interest: [A Programmer's Analysis of Boggle](http://www.robertgamble.net/2016/01/a-programmers-analysis-of-boggle.html) - Notes that there is two set of letters used in the actual 4x4 game, prior 1992 and post 1992.

Comment: @GuyCoder I managed to tune it down from about 30s (first version) to around 100ms for the 4 3 8 parameter set. No change in algorithmic complexity. Only reducing the constant time aspects of the implementation.

Comment: Of interest: [The Boggle Problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/814550/the-boggle-problem)

Comment: Of interest: [Solving the Boggle Game - Recursion, Prefix Tree, and Dynamic Programming](http://exceptional-code.blogspot.com/2012/02/solving-boggle-game-recursion-prefix.html)

Answer (score 1):

As for the non-optimization of the generation of sets.
The second version posted in the update to the question showed, that this is actually the case (not optimized by compiler) and it yielded a significant speed up. The final version (posted below in this answer) carries that approach even further and speeds up the path counting (and the solving of a boggle puzzle) even further.

Combined with parallel execution on multiple cores, the initially really slow (maybe 30s) version could be sped up to only around 100ms for the `n=4 lmin=3 lmax=8` case.

For n=6 class of problems, the parallel and hand tuned implementation solves a puzzle in around 60ms on my machine. It makes sense, that this is faster than the path counting, as the word list probing (used a dictionary with around 80000 words) along with the dynamic programming approach pointed out by @GuyCoder renders the solution of the puzzle a less complex problem than the (brute force) path counting.

### Lesson learned

The f# compiler does not seem to be all too mystical and magical if it comes to code optimizations. Hand tuning is worth the effort if performance is really required.

Turning a single threaded recursive search function into a parallel (concurrent) function was not really hard in this case.

### The final version of the code

Compiled with:

> fsc --optimize+ --tailcalls+ wordgames.fs

(Microsoft (R) F# Compiler version 14.0.23413.0)

```
let wordListPath = @"E:\temp\12dicts-6.0.2\International\3of6all.txt"

let acceptableWord (s : string) : bool =
    let s' = s.Trim()
    if s'.Length > 2
    then
        if System.Char.IsLower(s'.[0]) && System.Char.IsLetter(s'.[0]) then true
        else false
    else
        false

let words = 
    System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(wordListPath)
    |> Array.filter acceptableWord


let squareSet n =
    let allSquares = [0..n*n-1] |> Set.ofList
    let right = Set.difference allSquares (Set.ofList [n-1..n..n*n])
    let left = Set.difference allSquares (Set.ofList [0..n..n*n-1])
    let up = Set.difference allSquares (Set.ofList [0..n-1])
    let down = Set.difference allSquares (Set.ofList [n*n-n..n*n-1])
    let downRight = Set.intersect right down
    let downLeft = Set.intersect left down
    let upRight = Set.intersect right up
    let upLeft = Set.intersect left up
    [|right;left;up;down;upRight;upLeft;downRight;downLeft|]    

let RIGHT,LEFT,UP,DOWN = 0,1,2,3
let UPRIGHT,UPLEFT,DOWNRIGHT,DOWNLEFT = 4,5,6,7

let squareSets =
    [|Set.empty;Set.empty;Set.empty;Set.empty;Set.empty;Set.empty;Set.empty;Set.empty;|]
    ::
    [    for i in 1..8 do
            yield squareSet i
    ]
    |> Array.ofList


let movesFromSquare n square =
    let appendIfInSet se v res =
            if Set.contains square se then v :: res  else res

    []
    |> appendIfInSet squareSets.[n].[RIGHT] (square + 1)
    |> appendIfInSet squareSets.[n].[LEFT] (square - 1)
    |> appendIfInSet squareSets.[n].[UP] (square - n)
    |> appendIfInSet squareSets.[n].[DOWN] (square + n)
    |> appendIfInSet squareSets.[n].[DOWNRIGHT] (square + n + 1)
    |> appendIfInSet squareSets.[n].[DOWNLEFT] (square + n - 1)
    |> appendIfInSet squareSets.[n].[UPRIGHT] (square - n + 1)
    |> appendIfInSet squareSets.[n].[UPLEFT] (square - n - 1)

let lutMovesN n =
    Array.init n (fun i -> if i > 0 then Array.init (n*n-1) (fun j -> movesFromSquare i j) else Array.empty)

let lutMoves =
    lutMovesN 8

let moves n state square =
    let appendIfInSet se v res =
            if Set.contains square se then v :: res  else res

    lutMoves.[n].[square]
    |> List.filter (fun s -> ((uint64 1 <<< s) &&& state) = 0UL)

let block state square =
    state ||| (uint64 1 <<< square)

let countAllPaths n lmin lmax =
    let mov = moves n
    let rec count l state sq c =
        let state' = block state sq
        let m = mov state' sq
        match l with
        | x when x <= lmax && x >= lmin ->
            List.fold (fun acc s -> count (l+1) state' s acc) (c+1) m
        | x when x < lmin ->
            List.fold (fun acc s -> count (l+1) state' s acc) (c) m
        | _ ->
            c
    //List.fold (fun acc s -> count 0 (block 0UL s) s acc) 0 [0..n*n-1]
    [|0..n*n-1|]
    |> Array.Parallel.map (fun start -> count 0 (block 0UL start) start 0)
    |> Array.sum


//printfn "%d " (words |> Array.distinct |> Array.length)

let usage() =
    printfn "usage: wordgames.exe [--gen n count problemPath | --count n lmin lmax | --solve problemPath ]"

let rng = System.Random()

let genProblem n (sb : System.Text.StringBuilder) =
    let a = Array.init (n*n) (fun _ -> char (rng.Next(26) + int 'a'))
    sb.Append(a) |> ignore
    sb.AppendLine()

let genProblems nproblems n (sb : System.Text.StringBuilder) : System.Text.StringBuilder =
    for i in 1..nproblems do
        genProblem n sb |> ignore
    sb

let solve n (board : System.String) =
    let ba = board.ToCharArray()

    let testWord (w : string) : bool =
        let testChar k sq = (ba.[sq] = w.[k])
        let rec testSquare state k sq =
            match k with
            | 0 -> testChar 0 sq
            | x -> 
                if testChar x sq
                then
                    let state' = block state x
                    moves n state' x
                    |> List.exists (testSquare state' (x-1))
                else
                    false

        [0..n*n-1]    
        |> List.exists (testSquare 0UL (String.length w - 1))

    words
    |> Array.splitInto 32
    |> Array.Parallel.map (Array.filter testWord)
    |> Array.concat

[<EntryPoint>] 
let main args =
    printfn "%d: %A" (Array.length args) args
    let nargs = Array.length args
    let sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()
    match nargs with
    | x when x >= 2 ->
        match args.[0] with
        | "--gen" ->
            if nargs = 4
            then
                let n = int args.[1]
                let nproblems = int args.[2]
                let outpath = args.[3]
                let problems = genProblems nproblems n (System.Text.StringBuilder())
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText (outpath,problems.ToString())
                0
            else
                usage()
                0
        | "--count" ->
            if nargs = 4 
            then
                let n = int args.[1]
                let lmin = int args.[2]
                let lmax = int args.[3]
                sw.Start()
                let count = countAllPaths n lmin lmax
                sw.Stop()
                printfn "%d %d %d -> %d (took: %d)" n lmin lmax count (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)
                0
            else
                usage ()
                0
        | "--solve" ->
            if nargs = 2
            then
                let problems = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(args.[1])
                problems 
                |> Array.iter 
                    (fun (p : string) -> 
                        let n = int (sqrt (float (String.length p)))
                        sw.Reset()
                        sw.Start()
                        let found = solve n p
                        sw.Stop()
                        printfn "%s\n%A\n%dms" p found (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)
                    )
                0
            else
                usage ()
                0
        | _ ->
            usage ()
            0
    | _ -> 
        usage ()
        0
```

Comment: I haven't looked at this code in great detail yet, but correct me if this these statements are wrong. Your original question was about counting the paths, not about finding the words. Then in this answer you noted that the `dynamic programming approach` which does not find all of the paths and count them, but instead is used to determine if a word is on the grid. Thus the answer with `dynamic programming approach` is not an answer to the original question. Did I miss something.

Comment: @GuyCoder The original question was about what can be expected from the F# compiler in the optimization category. Not too much as this question shows. The "optimizable" 8 sets in the original code did not get optimized. So the (undesired) code bloat could not be avoided. The hand written optimizations, which do bloat the code increased performance beyond of what the original code can achieve with optimizing compile. The few extra lines showing the solve function do not invalidate the findings regarding the original question. And if you call the program with ``--count 4 3 8`` you still count.

Comment: Ahh, I see you were after optimizations first. Thanks.