# How to build a NxN Boggle game board in Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit

Recently, I built a web based [Boggle solver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746082/how-to-find-list-of-possible-words-from-a-letter-matrix-boggle-solver) which looks like this:

[image]

The UI let's the user select a grid size, enter the letters and display the board.

As a programming exercise, I want to build a Mac native app using Cocoa that does the same thing. I am a bit rusty on AppKit, and I need some advice on what layout elements I can use to build the NxN board. I checked the documentation, and it looks like NSMatrix might be what I need, but it is deprecated and it's use is discouraged. I would also like each cell in the board to be a TextField where the user can type a letter directly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at `NSCollectionView`.

Answer (score 1):

To create a grid of elements that can be updated dynamically, your best choice would be `NSCollectionView`. Each cell in your collection view would have a `NSTextField` inside to be used as the label. To learn more about how to implement `NSCollectionView` check out Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscollectionview).